# Why is template argument deduction disabled with std::forward?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, c++11

In VS2010 std::forward is defined as such:

```
template<class _Ty> inline
_Ty&& forward(typename identity<_Ty>::type& _Arg)
{   // forward _Arg, given explicitly specified type parameter
    return ((_Ty&&)_Arg);
}
```

`identity` appears to be used solely to disable template argument deduction. What's the point of purposefully disabling it in this case?

Comment: Note that currently `std::forward` is declared as `template<typename T> T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t); template<typename T> T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t);` (and both return `static_cast<T&&>(t)`). MSVC is following a previous version of `forward`.

Comment: Interesting. How is that different from `template<typename T> T&& forward(T&& t){ return static_cast<T&&>(t); }`? I see the purpose of `std::remove_reference` in `std::move`, but not here.

Comment: The two overload version works with rvalues and doesn't require `std:identity` which was in fact dropper altogether from the Standard.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you pass an rvalue reference to an object of type `X` to a template function that takes type `T&&` as its parameter, template argument deduction deduces `T` to be `X`. Therefore, the parameter has type `X&&`. If the function argument is an lvalue or const lvalue, the compiler deduces its type to be an lvalue reference or const lvalue reference of that type.

**If `std::forward` used template argument deduction:**

Since `objects with names are lvalues` the only time `std::forward` would correctly cast to `T&&` would be when the input argument was an unnamed rvalue (like `7` or `func()`). In the case of perfect forwarding the `arg` you pass to `std::forward` is an lvalue because it has a name. `std::forward`'s type would be deduced as an lvalue reference or const lvalue reference. Reference collapsing rules would cause the `T&&` in `static_cast<T&&>(arg)` in std::forward to always resolve as an lvalue reference or const lvalue reference.

**Example:**

```
template<typename T>
T&& forward_with_deduction(T&& obj)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(obj);
}

void test(int&){}
void test(const int&){}
void test(int&&){}

template<typename T>
void perfect_forwarder(T&& obj)
{
    test(forward_with_deduction(obj));
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    const int& y(x);
    int&& z = std::move(x);

    test(forward_with_deduction(7));    //  7 is an int&&, correctly calls test(int&&)
    test(forward_with_deduction(z));    //  z is treated as an int&, calls test(int&)

    //  All the below call test(int&) or test(const int&) because in perfect_forwarder 'obj' is treated as
    //  an int& or const int& (because it is named) so T in forward_with_deduction is deduced as int& 
    //  or const int&. The T&& in static_cast<T&&>(obj) then collapses to int& or const int& - which is not what 
    //  we want in the bottom two cases.
    perfect_forwarder(x);           
    perfect_forwarder(y);           
    perfect_forwarder(std::move(x));
    perfect_forwarder(std::move(y));
}
```

Comment: Great that you got your head wrapped around how and why `std::forward` works like it does. :) +1

Comment: Do note that just removing `remove_reference` will keep everything working - as long as `forward` accepts by `&` and you keep the explicit template specification when calling it. The explicit template specification is required to make this work, so `remove_reference` makes sure we don't forget it. Your example with the forwarding reference (`&&`) is a red herring, IMHO

Comment: Amateur programmer here in 2024.  I was gonna ask if this still applies in C++23 but given the answer I feel like it still does.  Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Because `std::forward(expr)` is not useful. The only thing it can do is a no-op, i.e. perfectly-forward its argument and act like an identity function. The alternative would be that it's the same as `std::move`, but we *already* have that. In other words, assuming it were possible, in

```
template<typename Arg>
void generic_program(Arg&& arg)
{
    std::forward(arg);
}
```

`std::forward(arg)` is semantically equivalent to `arg`. On the other hand, `std::forward<Arg>(arg)` is not a no-op in the general case.

So by forbidding `std::forward(arg)` it helps catch programmer errors and we lose nothing since any possible use of `std::forward(arg)` are trivially replaced by `arg`.

---

I think you'd understand things better if we focus on what exactly `std::forward<Arg>(arg)` *does*, rather than what `std::forward(arg)` would do (since it's an uninteresting no-op). Let's try to write a no-op function template that perfectly forwards its argument.

```
template<typename NoopArg>
NoopArg&& noop(NoopArg&& arg)
{ return arg; }
```

This naive first attempt isn't quite valid. If we call `noop(0)` then `NoopArg` is deduced as `int`. This means that the return type is `int&&` and we can't bind such an rvalue reference from the expression `arg`, which is an lvalue (it's the name of a parameter). If we then attempt:

```
template<typename NoopArg>
NoopArg&& noop(NoopArg&& arg)
{ return std::move(arg); }
```

then `int i = 0; noop(i);` fails. This time, `NoopArg` is deduced as `int&` (reference collapsing rules guarantees that `int& &&` collapses to `int&`), hence the return type is `int&`, and this time we can't bind such an lvalue reference from the expression `std::move(arg)` which is an xvalue.

In the context of a perfect-forwarding function like `noop`, *sometimes* we want to move, but other times we don't. The rule to know whether we should move depends on `Arg`: if it's not an lvalue reference type, it means `noop` was passed an rvalue. If it is an lvalue reference type, it means `noop` was passed an lvalue. So in `std::forward<NoopArg>(arg)`, `NoopArg` is a *necessary* argument to `std::forward` in order for the function template to do the right thing. Without it, there's not enough information. This `NoopArg` is **not** the same type as what the `T` parameter of `std::forward` would be deduced in the general case.

Comment: So what does `std::forward<T>(t)` do differently from `std::forward(t)`?

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a no-op if it deduced the template argument type instead of me explicitly giving it. Could you elaborate/clarify?

Comment: "any possible use of std::forward(t) are trivially replaced by t" I don't think that's true; the former is an r-value, the latter is not.

Comment: @avakar No. Since we're passing a variable to `std::forward`, `T` would be deduced to an lvalue reference type and reference collapsing rules would ensure that the return type is that same lvalue reference type, thus the call would be an lvalue. Similarly, `std::forward(0)` would be an xvalue. Hence, a deducing `std::forward` would perfectly forward its argument and be a no-op.

Comment: I noticed an overuse of `template<typename T>`, I changed my latest example to `template<typename U>` to distinguish from the template parameter of `std::forward`. I think it helps with understanding that when perfect-forwarding is involved, a deduced parameter can be a reference type.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I can't make sense of half of what you wrote. Alot of it appears to be attempting to explain things I already knew. I think you're trying to say template argument deduction would result in T equaling the wrong type in certain cases - though I can't see why.

Comment: @Dave I'm also having trouble explaining as I don't know my target audience. Since rvalue references, reference collapsing rules and template parameter deduction were all special purposed to make perfect forwarding possible it's a bit hard to explain any one aspect of it without getting tangled in the whole bit. Do you understand what is the value category of `std::forward<U>(U)` and can you compare it to the value category of a hypothetical `std::forward(u);`?

Comment: Regarding your first post: _std::forward(t) is semantically equivalent to t_ - that seems wrong. Since `t` is _named_ shouldn't that make it impossible to use as an rvalue reference even when T = int&& (unless you explicitly cast it to a T&& (which would be the point of std::forward, right?)

Comment: @Dave Right. But `t` isn't used as an rvalue reference, I'm not sure why you mention that. Do you mean binding to the parameter of `std::forward`? Do you understand that in `template<typename T> void foo(T&&);` then `T&&` may or may not be an rvalue reference?

Comment: @Luc : It seems clear they don't understand reference collapsing rules.

Comment: Sort of a nit, I guess, but: "Similarly, std::forward(0) would be an xvalue. Hence, a deducing std::forward would perfectly forward its argument and be a no-op." Aren't you contradicting yourself here? 0 isn't an xvalue, std::forward(0) is an xvalue, so a deducing std::forward wouldn't be a no-op, it would turn prvalues into xvalues. The difference can be observed when declaring a variable of type decltype(forward(0)) vs. one declared decltype(0). It's still completely useless, though.

Comment: @hvd Function templates cannot tell prvalues apart from xvalues. The final, bound argument is a ‘value’ of type `int&&`, and it is the return ‘value’ as well. Hence, a no-op.

Comment: Indeed, you really need decltype to tell them apart, function templates wouldn't be enough for that.

Comment: @LucDanton, I bumped into this answer while studying _Effective Modern C++_ by Scott Mayers, since I haven't mastered perfect `forward`ing completely (I'm a bit more comfortable with `move`, though!). Anyway, Mayers writes an implementation of `std:forward` to make the topic less elusive, but, unfortunately, he doesn't make explicit difference between the template parameter relative to the template implementation of `forward` (he uses `T`) and the that of the no-op function template (he uses `T`, you used `U`).

Comment: (@LucDanton, comment continued here) Maybe inserting that chunk could help readers (_e.g._ me) that consider themeselves as being exactly on the line between _having a vague idea_ and _having catched the secret_. Maybe you could take it as an occasione to give the definitive revision to your already remarkable answer.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I deliberately avoid revealing or talking too much about an implementation of `std::forward` because I consider it a hallmark of good programming to code against the interface, not the implementation. That is of course a bit self-defeating here, due to the importance of this `T` parameter (which is part of the interface, but serves a very messy, gritty purpose nonetheless). That being said, your comments are on point (and appreciated) and I can at the very least improve on these awful single-letter template parameter names.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Because for `std::forward` to work as **intended**(, i.e. to faitfully pass the original type info), it is **meant** to be **used** **INSIDE TEMPLATE CONTEXT**, and it **must use the deduced type param** from the **enclosing template context**, **instead** of deducing the type param **by itself**(, since only the enclosing templates have the chance to deduce the true type info, this will be explained in the details), hence the type param must be provided.

Though using `std::forward` inside non-template context is possible, it is **pointless**(, will be explained in the details).

And if anyone dares to try implementing `std::forward` to allow type deducing, he/she is doomed to fail painfully.

**Details:**

Example:

```
template <typename T>
auto someFunc(T&& arg){ doSomething(); call_other_func(std::forward<T>(para)); }
```

Observer that `arg` is declared as `T&&`,( it is the key to deduce the true type passed, and) it is not a rvalue reference, though it has the same syntax, it is called an **universal reference** ([Terminology coined by Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)), because `T` is a generic type, (likewise, in `string s; auto && ss = s;` ss is not a rvalue reference).

Thanks to **universal reference**, some type deduce magic happens when `someFunc` is being instantiated, specifically as following:

- If an rvalue object, which has the type `_T` or `_T &`, is passed to `someFunc`, `T` will be deduced as `_T &`(, yeah, even if the type of `X` is just `_T`, please read [Meyers' artical](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers))；
- If an rvalue of type `_T &&` is passed to `someFunc`，`T` will be deduced as `_T &&`

Now, you can replace `T` with the true type in above code:

When lvalue obj is passed:

```
auto someFunc(_T & && arg){ doSomething(); call_other_func(std::forward<_T &>(arg)); }
```

And after applying **reference collapse rule**(, pls read [Meyers' artical](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)), we get:

```
auto someFunc(_T & arg){ doSomething(); call_other_func(std::forward<_T &>(arg)); }
```

When rvalue obj is passed:

```
auto someFunc(_T && && arg){ doSomething(); call_other_func(std::forward<_T &&>(arg)); }
```

And after applying reference collapse rule(, pls read [Meyers' artical](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)), we get:

```
auto someFunc(_T && arg){ doSomething(); call_other_func(std::forward<_T &&>(arg)); }
```

Now, you can guess what std::forwrd does eseentially is just `static_cast<T>(para)`(, in fact, in **clang** 11's implementation it is `static_cast<T &&>(para)`, which is the same after applying reference collapsing rule). Everything works out fine.

But if you think about let std::fowrd deducing the type param by itself, you'll quickly find out that **inside `someFunc`**, **`std::forward` literally** **IS NOT ABLE TO deduce the original type** of `arg`.

If you try to make the compiler do it, it will **never be deduced as `_T &&`**(, yeah, even **when `arg` is bind to an `_T &&`**, it is still **an lvaule obj inside `someFunc`**, hence can only be deduceed as `_T` or `_T &`.... you really should read [Meyers' artical](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)).

Last, why should you only use `std::forward` inside templates? Because in non-templates context, you know exactly what type of obj you have. So, if you have an **lvalue** **bind** to an **rvalue reference**, and you need to **pass it as an lvaule** to another function, just pass it, or if you need to **pass it as rvalue**, **just do `std::move`**. You simply **DON'T NEED** **std::forward** inside non-template context.