# binding a lvalue to a rvalue reference under MSVS2010

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010, rvalue-reference

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    T v_;

    Foo(T&& v):v_(std::forward<T>(v))
    {
        std::cout << "building Foo..\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    int v;
    Foo<int> foo(v);

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

visual c++ 2010 output :

> error C2664: `'Foo<T>::Foo(T &&)'` : cannot convert parameter 1 from `'int'` to `'int &&'`

Is it normal that I can't bind a lvalue to a rvalue reference ?

**EDIT:**

same thing for a function :

```
void f(int && v)
{

}
int v;
f(v); //won't compile
```

I'm a little bit confused because I think std::forward is usefull to detect if a method is called with a lvalue or a rvalue reference.
But it seems that we can't bind any lvalue into rvalue reference... at least without template parameter but I don't understand it very well

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Reference-collapsing rules would only apply if the constructor itself is a template.

Comment: @ildjarn: thanks, do you know the reason of that ?

Comment: If reference-collapsing rules always applied to rvalue-reference syntax regardless of context then it wouldn't be possible to specifically denote a true rvalue-reference, which wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @ildjarn: I have edited my post because I don't really understand your last comment

Comment: In `void f(int && v)`, `v` is always an rvalue-reference. In `template<typename U> void f(U && v)`, `v` can be an rvalue-reference or an lvalue-reference due to reference-collapsing rules.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526598/how-does-stdforward-work/8527373#8527373) might make it more clear to you.

Comment: In your example, int i = 5;   some_struct<int> s2(i); I don't get why in ctor i is detect as int& and not as int,

Comment: Because you're passing an lvalue, not an rvalue.

Comment: there is still something I don't understand...in the following example: int v = 5; f(int v); f(v); It seems I will pass 'v' as I pass 'i' in the previsous example,but here I have a int not a int&. So why 'i' (which was intially a int) become a int& when we try to bind it into a rvalue reference

Comment: An lvalue can copied into a new value, as in `int v = 5; f(int v); f(v);`. However, an lvalue cannot be bound to an rvalue-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal that calling a move constructor requires an r-value, not an l-value, since an l-value could be named after the move constructor runs, and using a moved-from value would evoke unintended behavior.