# rvalue template argument implicitly used as lvalue, and std::forwarding working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

[This example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) on the usage of `std::forward` is puzzling me. This is my edited version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    A(int&& n) { cout << "rvalue overload, n=" << n << "\n"; }
    A(int& n)  { cout << "lvalue overload, n=" << n << "\n"; }
};

template<typename> void template_type_dumper();

template<class T, class U>
unique_ptr<T> make_unique(U&& u){
    //Have a "fingerprint" of what function is being called
    static int dummyvar;
    cout<<"address of make_unique::dummyvar: "<<&dummyvar<<endl;
    //g++ dumps two warnings here, which reveal what exact type is passed as template parameter
    template_type_dumper<decltype(u)>;
    template_type_dumper<U>;

    return unique_ptr<T>(new T(forward<U>(u)));
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A> p1 = make_unique<A>(2); // rvalue
    int i = 1;
    unique_ptr<A> p2 = make_unique<A>(i); // lvalue
}
```

The output is

```
address of make_unique::dummyvar: 0x6021a4
rvalue overload, n=2
address of make_unique::dummyvar: 0x6021a8
lvalue overload, n=1
```

and the warnings about reference to `template_type_dumper` show that in the first instantiation, `decltype(u) = int&&` and `U = int`, for the second `decltype(u) = int&` and `U = int&`.

It's evident that there are two different instantiations as expected, but her are my questions:

1. how can `std::forward` work here? In the first instantiation, its template argument is explicitly `U = int`, how can it know that it has to return a rvalue-reference? What would happen if I specified `U&&` instead?
2. `make_unique` is declared to take a rvalue-reference. How come `u` can be a lvalue-reference? Is there any special rule that I am missing?

Comment: You're missing [_reference collapsing_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527373/636019).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `make_unique` is declared to take a rvalue-reference. How come u can be a lvalue-reference? Is there any special rule that I am missing?

`make_unique` is declared to take a reference. What kind that reference is is to be deduced. If an lvalue of type `foo` is passed, `U` is deduced as `foo&` and `U&&` becomes `foo&` because of the reference collapsing rules (basically, "combining" an lvalue reference with another reference always produces an lvalue reference; combining two rvalue references produces an rvalue reference). If an rvalue of type `foo` is passed, `U` is deduced as `foo` and `U&&` is `foo&&`.

This is one of the things that powers perfect forwarding: with `U&&` you can take both lvalues and rvalues, and `U` is deduced to match the appropriate value category. Then with `std::forward` you can forward the values preserving that same value category: in the first case, you get `std::forward<foo&>` which forwards an lvalue, and in the second one, you get `std::forward<foo>` which forwards an rvalue.

> In the first instantiation, its template argument is explicitly U = int, how can it know that it has to return a rvalue-reference?

Because the return type of `std::forward<T>` is always `T&&`. If you pass `int` it returns `int&&`. If you pass `int&` it returns `int&` again because of the reference collapsing rules.

> What would happen if I specified U&& instead?

You would have `std::forward<int&&>` and the reference collapsing rules make `int&& &&` an rvalue reference still: `int&&`.

Comment: A pity that most of the online articles seems to focus more on move semantics when explaining rvalue-references rather than on this reference collapsing mechanism, which basically answers all my questions.

Comment: `U` is a type, so it doesn't really have a "value category". Rather, `U` is deduced either as a non-reference or an lvalue-reference type.

Comment: @KerrekSB I fixed the wording :)

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: Move semantics are the most generally useful. Reference collapsing and so forth are a lot more complex to describe and only useful if you're writing a template forwarding function. Which is not something everyone does.