# Pass functors by value or by C++11 Universal Reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, argument-passing, higher-order-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should templated functions take lambda arguments by value or by rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548614/should-templated-functions-take-lambda-arguments-by-value-or-by-rvalue-reference)

The C++ standard library functions take functor (function pointer or function object) arguments by value, like so:

```
template <typename F>
void apply(F func)
{
    func();
}
```

...But wouldn't it be better to pass functors by [Universal Reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers/)? Like so:

```
template <typename F>
void apply(F&& func)
{
    func();
}
```

This way you could pass function objects that maintain state, and have access to that (possibly modified) state after the higher-order function has returned.

Comment: The templates are expanded/resolved at compile time. How can they know about the state at the compile time?

Comment: Note that with the first one you can always use a reference-wrapper to avoid a copy.

Comment: @Manoj R: What I meant was: You have a function object variable fn_obj, you call apply(fn_obj), and then you have access to fn_obj.state, which might have been modified by the call to apply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already the case with some algorithms; for example, in `g++ 4.7.0`:

```
//stl_algo.h

template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
void
shuffle(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
    _UniformRandomNumberGenerator&& __g)
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously, it's imperative for things such as random number generators. I imagine this will become something more common in time, however.