# Template argument deduction - T is deduced and T&& used

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For the example

```
template <typename T>
void function(T&& arg)
```

Can somebody explain in detail how does it end that function signature becomes T& for lvalues and T&& for rvalues passed in ? I know that somehow(standard line needed) T -> T& in the case of lvalues and T -> T in case of revalues and then by combining & and && it results lvalue/rvalue reference.

Comment: Not really a duplicate but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward has the answer.

Comment: `T -> T` in the case of rvalues, actually. And I highly recommend watching [this video by Scott Meyers on this specific topic](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11).

Comment: I also recommend reading [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527373/500104) for a step-by-step explanation of how the deduction and reference collapsing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is found in section 8.3.2p6.

> If a typedef, a type *template-parameter*, or a *decltype-specifier* denotes a type `TR`
>   that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type "lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type "lvalue reference to `T`", while an attempt to create the type "rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type `TR`.

Or in tabular form:

```
TR   R

T&   &  -> T&  // lvalue reference to cv TR -> lvalue reference to T
T&   && -> T&  // rvalue reference to cv TR -> TR (lvalue reference to T)
T&&  &  -> T&  // lvalue reference to cv TR -> lvalue reference to T
T&&  && -> T&& // rvalue reference to cv TR -> TR (rvalue reference to T)
```

Comment: yes, but how do you explain T is T& and T is T&&. Is it always that for lvalues (be it of type reference or simple value) that we have T is T& ?

Comment: I think what's missing here is how template argument deduction plays into this.

Comment: @Ben in case I didn't make myself understood. In order to apply section 8.3.2p6 you have to say first T is T& or T is T -> composing to & and &&

Comment: @Ghita: the argument at the place of call is either an lvalue or an rvalue. That comes from the call, not from the template itself. Read the table as: if the object pass to the function is `TR` and the type of reference in the template is `R`, then the deduced type is ...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas but when a template type T is deduced from an rvalue reference the deduced type is not an rvalue reference: `template<typename T> void foo(T or T&&); foo(1);` -> T is int. So reference collapsing doesn't actually apply there.

Comment: @bames53: I am not sure I follow, the compiler knows that `1` is an *rvalue*, and if the template takes the argument by *rvalue-reference*, the table above will apply. The deduced type `T` (if you don't explicitly ask for `&&`) will never be an *rvalue-reference*, but if you take the argument as `T&&`, depending on the nature of the argument the `T&&` expression will end up representing `T&` or `T&&`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What I mean is that the type deduced from `1` is `int`, and therefore the type _template-parameter_ does not denote a reference type at all; this means that reference collapsing is not needed and the quoted paragraph does not apply.

Comment: @bames53: Oh, ok, I see. Your complaint is that the quote is from 8.3.2p6 and not from 14.8.2.1p3.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Actually I commented because I misread your statement; you said 'Read the table as:' which I saw as "Read the table _as-is_:', and of course the table _as-is_ doesn't cover the situation Ghita was asking about, though your alternative reading does.

Comment: So basically this paragraph (14.8.2.1p3) "If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a
reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-
unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in
place of A for type deduction" says how things work if argument is an lvalue that one wants to bind to an rvalue ref

Answer (score 4):

This is thanks to the reference collapsing rules. Assume that `U` is a non-reference type; then:

```
    T = U             T & = U &       T && = U &&
If  T = U &  ,  then  T & = U &  and  T && = U &    .
    T = U &&          T & = U &       T && = U &&
```

Therefore, if your function argument can bind to an lvalue reference of type `U`, then `T` must be de­duced as `U &` in order for `T &&` to become `U &`, and this is the only choice, since lvalues cannot bind to rvalue references. On the other hand, if your argument is an rvalue of type `U`, then `T` is de­duced as `U` so that `T &&` becomes `U &&` and your argument can bind.

The key point is that matching reference type is `T &&` (and not `T`!). However, since `arg` itself is a named variable and thus an lvalue, you must use `std::forward<T>(arg)` to create an *expression* that's identical to the one with which your function was called.

Comment: Looks like each row represents a consistent set.  Maybe it would help if the table used `T1` ... `T3`.