# What is the meaning of a variable with type auto&&?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, forwarding-reference

If you read code like

`auto&& var = foo();`

where `foo` is any function returning by value of type `T`. Then `var` is an lvalue of type rvalue reference to `T`. But what does this imply for `var`? Does it mean, we are allowed to steal the resources of `var`? Are there any reasonable situations when you should use `auto&&` to tell the reader of your code something like you do when you return a `unique_ptr<>` to tell that you have exclusive ownership? And what about for example `T&&` when `T` is of class type?

I just want to understand, if there are any other use cases of `auto&&` than those in template programming; like the ones discussed in the examples in this article [Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) by Scott Meyers.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. I understand how the type deduction works, but what is my code *saying* when I use `auto&&`? I've been thinking of looking at why a range-based for loop expands to use `auto&&` as an example, but haven't gotten round to it. Perhaps whoever answers can explain it.

Comment: Is this even legal? I mean instnce of T is destroyed immediatelly after `foo` returns, storing a rvalue ref to it sounds like UB to ne.

Comment: @aleguna This is perfectly legal. I do not want to return a reference or pointer to a local variable, but a value. The function `foo` might for example look like: `int foo(){return 1;}`.

Comment: @aleguna references to temporaries perform lifetime extension, just as in C++98.

Comment: @ecatmur, that's something new to me. So if in a function I declare local object on a stack, return a reference to it and someone stores that returned referece, it will work fine? Why do all compilers give warnings when I do this?

Comment: @aleguna lifetime extension only works with local temporaries, not functions returning references.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/567292

Answer (score 344, accepted):

By using `auto&& var = <initializer>` you are saying: **I will accept any initializer regardless of whether it is an lvalue or rvalue expression and I will preserve its constness**. This is typically used for *forwarding* (usually with `T&&`). The reason this works is because a forwarding reference, `auto&&` or `T&&`, will bind to *anything*.

You might say, well why not just use a `const auto&` because that will *also* bind to anything? The problem with using a `const` reference is that it's `const`! You won't be able to later bind it to any non-const references or invoke any member functions that are not marked `const`.

As an example, imagine that you want to get a `std::vector`, take an iterator to its first element and modify the value pointed to by that iterator in some way:

```
auto&& vec = some_expression_that_may_be_rvalue_or_lvalue;
auto i = std::begin(vec);
(*i)++;
```

This code will compile just fine regardless of the initializer expression. The alternatives to `auto&&` fail in the following ways:

```
auto         => will copy the vector, but we wanted a reference
auto&        => will only bind to modifiable lvalues
const auto&  => will bind to anything but make it const, giving us const_iterator
const auto&& => will bind only to rvalues
```

So for this, `auto&&` works perfectly! An example of using `auto&&` like this is in a range-based `for` loop. See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13241108/150634) for more details.

If you then use `std::forward` on your `auto&&` reference to preserve the fact that it was originally either an lvalue or an rvalue, your code says: **Now that I've got your object from either an lvalue or rvalue expression, I want to preserve whichever valueness it originally had so I can use it most efficiently - this might invalidate it.** As in:

```
auto&& var = some_expression_that_may_be_rvalue_or_lvalue;
// var was initialized with either an lvalue or rvalue, but var itself
// is an lvalue because named rvalues are lvalues
use_it_elsewhere(std::forward<decltype(var)>(var));
```

This allows `use_it_elsewhere` to rip its guts out for the sake of performance (avoiding copies) when the original initializer was a modifiable rvalue.

What does this mean as to whether we can or when we can steal resources from `var`? Well since the `auto&&` will bind to anything, we cannot possibly try to rip out `var`s guts ourselves - it may very well be an lvalue or even const. We can however `std::forward` it to other functions that may totally ravage its insides. As soon as we do this, we should consider `var` to be in an invalid state.

Now let's apply this to the case of `auto&& var = foo();`, as given in your question, where foo returns a `T` by value. In this case we know for sure that the type of `var` will be deduced as `T&&`. Since we know for certain that it's an rvalue, we don't need `std::forward`'s permission to steal its resources. In this specific case, *knowing that `foo` returns by value*, the reader should just read it as: **I'm taking an rvalue reference to the temporary returned from `foo`, so I can happily move from it.**

---

As an addendum, I think it's worth mentioning when an expression like `some_expression_that_may_be_rvalue_or_lvalue` might turn up, other than a "well your code might change" situation. So here's a contrived example:

```
std::vector<int> global_vec{1, 2, 3, 4};

template <typename T>
T get_vector()
{
  return global_vec;
}

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
  auto&& vec = get_vector<T>();
  auto i = std::begin(vec);
  (*i)++;
  std::cout << vec[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Here, `get_vector<T>()` is that lovely expression that could be either an lvalue or rvalue depending on the generic type `T`. We essentially change the return type of `get_vector` through the template parameter of `foo`.

When we call `foo<std::vector<int>>`, `get_vector` will return `global_vec` by value, which gives an rvalue expression. Alternatively, when we call `foo<std::vector<int>&>`, `get_vector` will return `global_vec` by reference, resulting in an lvalue expression.

If we do:

```
foo<std::vector<int>>();
std::cout << global_vec[0] << std::endl;
foo<std::vector<int>&>();
std::cout << global_vec[0] << std::endl;
```

We get the following output, as expected:

```
2
1
2
2
```

If you were to change the `auto&&` in the code to any of `auto`, `auto&`, `const auto&`, or `const auto&&` then we won't get the result we want.

---

An alternative way to change program logic based on whether your `auto&&` reference is initialised with an lvalue or rvalue expression is to use type traits:

```
if (std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(var)>::value) {
  // var was initialised with an lvalue expression
} else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(var)>::value) {
  // var was initialised with an rvalue expression
}
```

Comment: Can't we simply say `T vec = get_vector<T>();` inside function foo ? Or am I simplifying it to an absurd level :)

Comment: @Asterisk No bcoz T vec can only be assigned to lvalue in case of std::vector<int&> and if T is std::vector<int> then we will be using call by value which is inefficient

Comment: auto& gives me the same result. I'm using MSVC 2015. And GCC produces an error.

Comment: Here I'm using MSVC 2015, auto& gives the same results as that of auto&&.

Comment: Why is int i; auto&& j = i; allowed  but  int i; int&& j =i;  is not ?

Comment: @SeventhSon84 An rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue. Therefore, `auto&&` is deduced to be an `int&` (lvalue reference) when assigned an lvalue.
But `int&&` is an unconditional rvalue reference.
So you'd have to write `int&& j = std::move(i);` to make your intentions clear and promise at the same time that `i` will not be used thereafter.

Comment: @SergeyPodobry binding rvalues to non-const lvalue references is a non-standard Microsoft extension.

Comment: @ScumCoder Yeah. Newer VS versions work according to the Standard.

Answer (score 15):

First, I recommend reading [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527373/500104) as a side-read for a step-by-step explanation on how template argument deduction for universal references works.

> Does it mean, we are allowed to steal the resources of `var`?

Not necessarily. What if `foo()` all of a sudden returned a reference, or you changed the call but forgot to update the use of `var`? Or if you're in generic code and the return type of `foo()` might change depending on your parameters?

Think of `auto&&` to be exactly the same as the `T&&` in `template<class T> void f(T&& v);`, because it's (nearly<sup>†</sup>) exactly that. What do you do with universal references in functions, when you need to pass them along or use them in any way? You use `std::forward<T>(v)` to get the original value category back. If it was an lvalue before being passed to your function, it stays an lvalue after being passed through `std::forward`. If it was an rvalue, it will become an rvalue again (remember, a named rvalue reference is an lvalue).

So, how do you use `var` correctly in a generic fashion? Use `std::forward<decltype(var)>(var)`. This will work exactly the same as the `std::forward<T>(v)` in the function template above. If `var` is a `T&&`, you'll get an rvalue back, and if it is `T&`, you'll get an lvalue back.

So, back on topic: What do `auto&& v = f();` and `std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)` in a codebase tell us? **They tell us that `v` will be acquired and passed on in the most efficient way.** Remember, though, that after having forwarded such a variable, it's possible that it's moved-from, so it'd be incorrect use it further without resetting it.

Personally, I use `auto&&` in generic code when I need a *modifyable* variable. Perfect-forwarding an rvalue is modifying, since the move operation potentially steals its guts. If I just want to be lazy (i.e., not spell the type name even if I know it) and don't need to modify (e.g., when just printing elements of a range), I'll stick to `auto const&`.

---

† `auto` is in so far different that `auto v = {1,2,3};` will make `v` an `std::initializer_list`, whilst `f({1,2,3})` will be a deduction failure.

Comment: In the first part of your answer: I mean that if `foo()` returns a value-type `T`, then `var` (this expression) will be an lvalue and its type (of this expression) will be a rvalue reference to `T` (i.e. `T&&`).

Comment: @MWid: Makes sense, removed the first part.

Answer (score 4):

Consider some type `T` which has a move constructor, and assume

```
T t( foo() );
```

uses that move constructor.

Now, let's use an intermediate reference to capture the return from `foo`:

```
auto const &ref = foo();
```

this rules out use of the move constructor, so the return value will have to be copied instead of moved (even if we use `std::move` here, we can't actually move through a const ref)

```
T t(std::move(ref));   // invokes T::T(T const&)
```

However, if we use

```
auto &&rvref = foo();
// ...
T t(std::move(rvref)); // invokes T::T(T &&)
```

the move constructor is still available.

---

And to address your other questions:

> ... Are there any reasonable situations when you should use auto&& to tell the reader of your code something ...

The first thing, as Xeo says, is essentially *I'm passing X as efficiently as possible*, whatever type X is. So, seeing code which uses `auto&&` internally should communicate that it will use move semantics internally where appropriate.

> ... like you do when you return a unique_ptr<> to tell that you have exclusive ownership ...

When a function template takes an argument of type `T&&`, it's saying it may move the object you pass in. Returning `unique_ptr` explicitly gives ownership to the caller; accepting `T&&` may *remove* ownership from the caller (if a move ctor exists, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure your second example is valid. Don't you need to you perfect forwarding to invoke the move constructor?

Comment: This is wrong. In both cases the copy constructor is called, since `ref` and `rvref` are both lvalues. If you want the move constructor, then you have to write `T t(std::move(rvref))`.

Comment: Did you mean const ref in your first example: `auto const &`?

Comment: @aleguna - you and MWid are right, thanks. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @Useless You are right. But this doesn't answer my quetion. When do you use `auto&&` and what do you tell the reader of your code by using `auto&&`?

Answer (score -3):

The `auto &&` syntax uses two new features of C++11:

1. The `auto` part lets the compiler deduce the type based on the context (the return value in this case). This is without any reference qualifications (allowing you to specify whether you want `T`, `T &` or `T &&` for a deduced type `T`).
2. The `&&` is the new move semantics. A type supporting move semantics implements a constructor `T(T && other)` that optimally moves the content in the new type. This allows an object to swap the internal representation instead of performing a deep copy.

This allows you to have something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> foo();
```

So:

```
auto var = foo();
```

will perform a copy of the returned vector (expensive), but:

```
auto &&var = foo();
```

will swap the internal representation of the vector (the vector from `foo` and the empty vector from `var`), so will be faster.

This is used in the new for-loop syntax:

```
for (auto &item : foo())
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
```

Where the for-loop is holding an `auto &&` to the return value from `foo` and `item` is a reference to each value in `foo`.

Comment: This is incorrect. `auto&&` will not move anything, it will just make a reference. Whether it's an lvalue or rvalue reference depends on the expression used to initialize it.

Comment: In both cases will the move constructor be called, since `std::vector` and `std::string` are moveconstructible. This has nothing to do with the type of `var`.

Comment: @MWid: Actually, the call to the copy/move constructor could also be elided altogether with RVO.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You are right. But I think that in the above example, the copy cnstructor will never get called, since everything is moveconstructible.

Comment: @MWid: my point was that even the move constructor can be elided. Elision trumps move (it's cheaper).