# Why does a range-based for statement take the range by auto&&?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, language-design, forwarding-reference

A *range-based `for` statement* is defined in §6.5.4 to be equivalent to:

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
             __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

where `range-init` is defined for the two forms of range-based `for` as:

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression )         =>   ( expression )
for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list )   =>   braced-init-list
```

(the clause further specifies the meaning of the other sub-expressions)

Why is `__range` given the deduced type `auto&&`? My understanding of `auto&&` is that it's useful for preserving the original valueness (lvalue/rvalue) of an expression by passing it through `std::forward`. However, `__range` isn't passed anywhere through `std::forward`. It's only used when getting the range iterators, as one of `__range`, `__range.begin()`, or `begin(__range)`.

What's the benefit here of using the "universal reference" `auto&&`? Wouldn't `auto&` suffice?

Note: As far as I can tell, [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1868.html) doesn't say anything about the choice of `auto&&`.

Comment: This way you can use r-values in the range.

Comment: "*As far as I can tell, the proposal doesn't say anything about the choice of auto&&.*" And that proposal also uses the range library, which doesn't exist in C++11.

Comment: For future reference, the property of an expression described by e.g. 'lvalue' or 'rvalue' is its value category.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Wouldn't auto& suffice?

No, it wouldn't. It wouldn't allow the use of an *r-value expression* that computes a range. `auto&&` is used because it can bind to an l-value expression *or* an r-value expression. So you don't need to stick the range into a variable to make it work.

Or, to put it another way, this wouldn't be possible:

```
for(const auto &v : std::vector<int>{1, 43, 5, 2, 4})
{
}
```

> Wouldn't `const auto&` suffice?

No, it wouldn't. A `const std::vector` will only ever return `const_iterator`s to its contents. If you want to do a non-`const` traversal over the contents, that won't help.

Comment: Oops, I actually meant to ask if `const auto&` would suffice. Won't this bind to anything too?

Comment: @sftrabbit: It won't bind to a *non-const* l-value. A `const std::vector` will only return `const` iterators.

Comment: Thanks. This means that `auto&&` is also useful for binding to anything without making it `const`, in addition to forwarding.

Comment: Just to clarify: `for (const auto& v : std::vector<int>{1, 43, 5, 2, 4}) {}` is possible for a const traversal.

Comment: But then why would you want to modify the temporary vector you are iterating over inside the loop?

Comment: @fyzix: And what if it's *not* a temporary vector? See, you can't go changing the definition of range-based `for` based on whether the range is a temporary or not. So whatever you pick, `const auto&` or `auto&&` has to be the same in all cases. If you use `const auto&`, you can only ever have `const` iteration for all ranges. If you use `auto&&`, you can have whatever kind of iteration you want.

Comment: *"No, it wouldn't. It wouldn't allow the use of an r-value expression that computes a range."* ->Why is this possible then?: `for(auto &v : std::vector<int>{1, 43, 5, 2, 4}){...}`

Comment: @starriet: The `auto&&` in question is built by the range-based `for` mechanism. If range-based `for` *internally* used `auto&`, the code you posted would not compile. It uses `auto&&` to *allow* that code to compile. That's the point of my answer.

Comment: Oh, then I think @FelixGlas's comment above seems to have misunderstood your intention, right? `for (T v : std::vector<int>{1, 43, 5, 2, 4}) {}` would not be possible *regardless of* what `T` is, **if** range-based `for` internally used `auto&`. Reading [§8.6.4 The range-based for statement] of C++ standard document helped me to understand. Please let me know if I didn't understand correctly. Thank you.