# Accessing common struct members in std::variant

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, variant

I have trouble understanding how to use `std::variant` in C++17. Given two struct `A` and `B`, and a `std::vector<std::variant<A,B>> vs`, I would like to:

- Refer to a common struct member, e.g. `n`;
- Call a common function, e.g. `fun()` or `add()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int n;
    void fun() { std::cout << "fun\n"; }
    int add(int m) { return n+m; }
};
struct B {
    int n;
    void fun() { std::cout << "fun\n"; }
    int add(int m) { return n+m; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::variant<A,B>> vs;
    vs.push_back(A{10,11});
    vs.push_back(B{20,22});
    
    // How to refer to struct members without using std::get<v.index()>(v)?
    for (auto && v : vs) {
         // 1. How to refer to v.n?
         // 2. How to call v.fun()?
         // 3. How to call v.add() with input parameter m?
    }
}
```

I am told to use `std::visit`, but am too blunt to understand how it works. Could anyone show a simple example here?

Comment: Did you look at the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)?

Comment: Does the example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit help? What parts of it confuse you?

Comment: Thank you all. It seems I do not understand lambda expression...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `std::visit` with a lambda that has an `auto&&` parameter to access members that are common to all variant types. In your example:

```
for (auto&& v : vs) {
    std::visit([&](auto&& x){
        std::cout << x.n << x.add(1);
        x.fun();
    }, v);
}
```

Comment: Why `&&` if we don't intend to move from it?

Comment: @Vorac See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241108/why-does-a-range-based-for-statement-take-the-range-by-auto