# Expression templates: improving performance in evaluating expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, expression, simplify

By the expression templates technique, a matrix expression like

```
D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
```

is pretty much equivalent, in terms of computing performance, to a hand-written `for` loop.

Now, suppose that I have the following two expressions

```
D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
F = D*E;
cout << F << "\n";
```

In a "classical" implementation by expression templates, the computing performance will be pretty much the same as that of two `for` loops in sequence. This is because the expressions are evaluated immediately after the `=` operators are encountered.

My question is: is there any technique (for example, using placeholders?) to recognize that the values of `D` are actually unused and that the values of interest are the sole elements of `F`, so that only the expression

```
F = E*(A*B+sin(C)+3.);
```

is evaluated and the whole performance is equivalent to that of a single `for` loop?

Of course, such an hypothetical technique should also be able to return back to evaluate the expression

```
D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
```

if later in the code the values of `D` are needed.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT: Results experimenting the solution suggested by Evgeny**

Original instruction:

```
Result D=A*B-sin(C)+3.;
```

Computing time: 32ms

Two steps instruction:

```
Result Intermediate=A*B;
Result D=Intermediate-sin(C)+3.;
```

Computing time: 43ms

Solution with `auto`:

```
auto&& Intermediate=A*B;
Result D=Intermediate-sin(C)+3.;
```

Computing time: 32ms.

In conclusion, `auto&&` enabled to restore the original computing time of the single instruction case.

**EDIT: Summarizing relevant links, following the suggestions by Evgeny**

[Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

[What does auto tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us)

[Universal References in C++11](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf)

[C++ Rvalue References Explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)

[C++ and Beyond 2012: Scott Meyers - Universal References in C++11](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11)

Comment: Why would an arithmetic expression be the same as a `for` loop?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, because [expression templates](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicInsideEigenExample.html) would gather **full** expression, optimize it's structure (optionaly), and execute it as it would be a **for** loop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluation of [expression template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) typically happens when you save result to some **special** type like:

```
Result D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
```

Result type of expression:

```
A*B+sin(C)+3.
```

is not **Result**, but it is something that convertable to **Result**. And evaluation happens during such conversion.

---

> My question is: is there any technique (for example, using placeholders?) to recognize that the values of D are actually unused

Such kind of "transfromation":

```
Result D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
Result F = D*E;
```

to

```
Result F = (A*B+sin(C)+3.)*E;
```

Is possible when you do not evaluate D. To do this, typically you should capture D as it's real , **expression** type. For instance, with help of [**auto**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
auto &&D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
Result F = D*E;
```

---

However, you should be carefull - sometimes expression template captures references to it's operands, and if you have some **rvalue** which would expire after it's expression:

```
auto &&D = A*get_large_rvalue();
// At this point, result of **get_large_rvalue** is destructed
// And D has expiried reference
Result F = D*E;
```

Where **get_large_rvalue** is:

```
LargeMatrix get_large_rvalue();
```

It's result is **rvalue**, it expiries at the end of full expression when **get_large_rvalue** was called. If something within expression would store pointer/reference to it (for later evaluation) and you would "defer" evaluation - pointer/reference will outlive pointed/referenced object.

In order to prevent this, you should do:

```
auto &&intermediate = get_large_rvalue(); // it would live till the end of scope
auto &&D = A*intermediate ;
Result F = D*E;
```

---

> I'm not familiar with C++11 but, as I understand, auto asks the compiler to determine the type of a variable from its initialization

Yes, exactly. This is called [Type Inference/Deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).

C++98/03 had type deduction only for template functions, in C++11 there is **auto**.

> Do you know how do CUDA and C++11 interact each other?

I haven't used **CUDA** (though I used **OpenCL**), but I guess that there will be no any problems in **Host** code with C++11. Maybe some C++11 features are not supported within **Device** code, but for your purpose - you need **auto** only in **Host** code

> Finally, is there any possibility with only C++?

Do you mean pre-C++11? I.e. C++98/C++03?
Yes, it is possible, but it has more syntax noise, maybe that would be reason to reject it:

```
// somehwhere
{
    use_D(A*B+sin(C)+3.);
}
// ...
template<typename Expression>
void use_D(Expression D) // depending on your expression template library
                         //   it may be better to use (const Expression &e)
{
    Result F = D*E;
}
```

---

> I'm now using CUDA/Visual Studio 2010 under Windows. Could you please recommend a compiler/toolset/environment for both OS' to use C++11 in the framework of my interest (GPGPU and CUDA, in you know any)

MSVC 2010 does supports some parts of C++11. In particular it supports **auto**. So, if you need only **auto** from C++11 - MSVC2010 is OK.

But if you may use MSVC2012 - I would recommed to stick with it - it has much better C++11 support.

> Also, the trick auto &&intermediate = get_large_rvalue(); seems to be not "transparent" to a third party user (which is not supposed to know such an issue). Am I right? Any alternative?

If expression template stores references to some values, and you defer it's evaluation. You should be sure that all it's references are alive at the place of evaluation. Use any method which you want - it can be done without auto, like:

```
LargeMatrix temp = get_large_rvalue();
```

Or maybe even global/static variable (less prefered method).

> A last comment/question: to use auto &&D = A*B+sin(C)+3.; it seems that I should overload the operator= for assignments between two expressions, right?

No, such form does not requires nor copy/move assignment operator nor copy/move constructor.

Basically it just names temporary value, and prolongs it's lifetime to the end of scope. [Check this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us).

But, if you would use another form:

```
auto D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
```

In such case copy/move/conversion constructor maybe required in order to compile (though actual copy can be optimized away by compiler by use of [Copy Ellision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision))

> Also, switching between using auto (for the intermediate expressions) and Result to force calculation seems to be non-transparent to a third party user. Any alternative?

I am not sure if there is any alternative. This is by nature of expression templates. While you using them in expressions - they return some internal intermediate types, but when you store to some "special" type - evaluation is triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have already a matrix library using expression templates written in C++ and CUDA for GPGPU. I'm not familiar with C++11 but, as I understand, `auto` asks the compiler to determine the type of a variable from its initialization: very useful with expression templates. Do you know how do CUDA and C++11 interact each other? Also, could you better expand your last point (expiration of `rvalue`)? Does it mean that I could not "post"-evaluate `D`, if needed afterwards? Finally, is there any possibility with only C++ (avoiding C++11)? Very good point! Thank you!

Comment: I updated answer. By the way, which compiler/toolset/environment do you use?

Comment: Thank you again. +1 and accepted answer. In the past, I have used `nvcc/gcc` under `Linux`, but for some reasons I'm now using `CUDA/Visual Studio 2010` under `Windows`. Could you please recommend a compiler/toolset/environment for both OS' to use `C++11` in the framework of my interest (GPGPU and CUDA, in you know any). Also, the trick `auto &&intermediate = get_large_rvalue();` seems to be not "transparent" to a third party user (which is not supposed to know such an issue). Am I right? Any alternative?

Comment: A last comment/question: to use `auto &&D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;` it seems that I should overload the `operator=` for assignments between two expressions, right?

Comment: Also, switching between using `auto` (for the intermediate expressions) and `Result` to force calculation seems to be non-transparent to a third party user. Any alternative? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer with results of some experiments using `auto&&`. I have also summarized some links relevant to the topic of this post. Again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! It also worth to mention talk of Scott Mayers about universal references - http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11 , though he describes a little bit different aspect of &&.

Comment: Added the talk to the reference list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In c++11 you can use `auto`

```
auto D = A*B+sin(C)+3.;
```

assuming you are using expression templates, the type of D would be `<some template type which represents an expression>`.
Now, you have to use this carefully, because you are saving up some memory (no need to allocate space for a matrix) but depending on how you use it this may not be the best.

Think about

F = D*E

An element D[i][j] needs to be "visited" many times when computing D*E (actually n times where n is the size of the matrices). If D is a plain-matrix type this is no problem. If D is an expression you are evaluating it many, many times.

On the contray, doing

```
F = D + E
```

is fine.

Think about this: you can not write `F = E*(A*B+sin(C)+3.);` using only two nested loops.

Comment: Expression Template libraries can automaticly recognize when it is better to evaluate part of result to temporary and when not. For instance, [Eigen does this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html): **"Eigen determines automatically, for each sub-expression, whether to evaluate it into a temporary variable. Indeed, in certain cases it is better to evaluate immediately a sub-expression into a temporary variable, while in other cases it is better to avoid that."**

Comment: @sbabbi Thank you very much for your answer. Please, see also my comment to Evgeny Panasyuk. Actually, I do not understand why `F=D*E` should be different to `F=D+E`. Both involve elementwise operations. Could you better explain that? Thanks.

Comment: @JackOLantern, I think he meant that in case of D*E, each element of D is visited many times (N-times for square matricies), and it is better to cache D, not calculating each element many times. But in case of D+E - each element of D is visited exactly once, and it is OK to use "lazy" computation each time. Nevertheless, some expression template libraries can decide when to use caching and when not automaticly (see Eigen link posted above).

Comment: Let me clarify that by the symbol `*` I mean elementwise multiplication. Multiple visits to the elements of `D` are justified for non-elementwise (matrix-matrix) multiplications, isn't it?