# Expression template : unroll loop

Tags: c++

I have the same kind of questions that:
[Expression templates: improving performance in evaluating expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856122/expression-templates-improving-performance-in-evaluating-expressions)

My aim is to unroll loop of this expression

```
auto && intermediate = A+D*C
for(int i= 0; i<10 ;i++)
    intermediate = intermediate + B
Vector result = intermediate * E
```

I would like to have in intermediate the whole tree of binary expression and that finally operator=(Expression ) of the class Vector run the inspection of the graph
With my code it works only without the loop for ( I use the classical implementation of expression template , the one of Joel Falcou @cppcon 2015)

Edit : code compile issue due to the loop

if I uncomment the loop into the main I have the compiled error
need to run with c++11

g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename TBase, typename Derived>
struct BaseExpression
{
   Derived const& self() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }
   Derived & self() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
   TBase operator[](size_t szIdx) const { return self()[szIdx]; }
   size_t size() const {return self().size();}
};

template <typename TBase, typename Operator, typename OP1, typename OP2>
class Binary_Expression : public BaseExpression<TBase, Binary_Expression<TBase, Operator, OP1, OP2> >
{
public:
   Binary_Expression(OP1 const & a, OP2 const & b) : op1(a), op2(b){}
   TBase operator[] (size_t idx) const { return op(op1[idx], op2[idx]); }
   size_t size() const { return op1.size() != 0 ? op1.size() : op2.size(); }


private:
   const OP1 & op1;
   const OP2 & op2;
   Operator op;
};


template <typename TBase >
class Vector : public BaseExpression<TBase, Vector<TBase> >
{

public:
   explicit Vector(size_t szSizeN) : m_xMemory(szSizeN){}

   Vector(const Vector &orig): m_xMemory()
   { 
      this->copy(orig);
   }

   Vector & operator=(const Vector &orig)
   {
      if (&orig != this)
      {
         Vector temp(orig);
         this->swap(temp);
      }

      return *this;
   }

   Vector & operator=(TBase factor)
   {
      size_t szSizeN = size();
#pragma omp parallel for
      for (size_t idx = 0; idx < szSizeN; idx++)
      {
         m_xMemory[idx] = factor;
      }

      return *this;
   }

   template <typename Expression>
   Vector(const BaseExpression<TBase, Expression> &b) :m_xMemory(b.size())
   {
      size_t szSizeN = size();
#pragma omp parallel for
      for (size_t idx = 0; idx < szSizeN; idx++)
      {
         m_xMemory[idx] = b[idx];
      }

   }

   void swap(Vector &orig)
   {
      using std::swap;
      swap(m_xMemory, orig.m_xMemory);
   }

   TBase operator[] (size_t idx) const { return m_xMemory[idx]; }

   TBase & operator[] (size_t idx) { return m_xMemory[idx]; }

   size_t size() const { return m_xMemory.size(); }

   void print()
   {
      size_t szSizeN = size();
      for (size_t idx = 0; idx < szSizeN; idx++)
      {
         std::cout << "Index=" << idx << "\t" << "Value=" << m_xMemory[idx] << std::endl;

      }
   }

private:
   void copy(const Vector &orig) 
   {
      m_xMemory = orig.m_xMemory;
   }

   std::vector<TBase> m_xMemory;
};


template <typename TBase, typename E1, typename E2>
Binary_Expression<TBase, std::plus<TBase>, E1, E2> operator+(const BaseExpression<TBase, E1> & xE1, const BaseExpression< TBase, E2> & xE2)
{
   return Binary_Expression<TBase, std::plus<TBase>, E1, E2>(xE1.self(), xE2.self());
}


int main()
{
   Vector<double> x1(10);
   Vector<double> x2(10);
   Vector<double> x3(10);

   x1 = 7.5;
   x2 = 8.;
   x3 = 4.2;

   auto && intermediate =  x1 + x2;


//compil error   
/*
   for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
   {
       intermediate = intermediate + x3;   
   }
   */
   // inspection of the graph here
   Vector<double> result = intermediate + x2;


   result.print();   

}
```

in fact in my final design I would like to write the following stuff :

```
   Vector<double> x1(10);
   Vector<double> x2(10);
   Vector<double> x3(10);

   x1 = 7.5;
   x2 = 8.;
   x3 = 4.2;

   Vector<double> intermediate = x1 + x2;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
       intermediate = intermediate + x3;

   Vector<double> result = x1 + x3 + intermediate;
   // finally into result I have the expression tree, and evaluate method which will make the graph inspection
   result.evaluate();
```

Thanks in advance
Jonathan

Comment: what is A, D, C, Vector and E? It's not easy to guess...

Comment: Yes  each capital letters is a vector

Comment: "a vector" is not an MCVE. You need to post code that compiles.

Comment: Ok , I have edited my post. The code is more complicated because I play on cpu and gpu but I have not code the Device part

Comment: No, a link is not a [mcve]. Make the effort to reduce your code to the bare minimum that still produces your problem and paste the entirety here.

Comment: Sorry, very difficult with a smartphone. I will create a sample reproducer in a copple of hours

Comment: Done, I added a sample example that express well what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that won't work, because the linked technique relies on the type of the `intermediate` variable capturing the whole expression. So it will look something like `Sum<Mult<Vector,Vector>>` (simplification here). But the type can not change in each iteration of the for loop.

I see to alternatives:

Do not capture the expression as the type, but as a runtime structure, of type let's say VectorExpression. This will have performance impacts, because you have to analyze the expression graph at runtime and limits the kinds of optimization you can do.

The second alternative would be to write your own for loop using template metaprogramming (with having a fresh type for each step).

Example of the fold function (which is what you want). We must use a fold functor, because partial specialization for functions is not supported:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <int N, class V, class F>
struct foldf {
    auto operator()(V v, F&& f) -> decltype(auto) {
        auto next = f(v);
        return foldf<N - 1, decltype(next), F>()(next, std::move(f));
    }
};

template <class V, class F>
struct foldf<0, V, F> {
    auto operator()(V v, F&& f) -> decltype(auto) {
        return v;
    }
};

// just a helper to make usage simpler
template <int N>
class Repeat{};

template <int N, class V, class F>
auto fold(Repeat<N> tag, V v, F&& f) -> decltype(auto) {
    return foldf<N, V, F>()(v, std::move(f));
}
```

To demonstrate that it does what we want, let's add this code:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Test {
};

class Other{};

template <class T>
auto wrap(T t) -> decltype(auto) {
    return Test<T>();
}

int main() {
    auto v = fold(Repeat<3>(), 0, [](auto t){ 
        return wrap(t); 
    });
    Other x = v;
}
```

The result should be `tmp.cpp:42:11: error: no viable conversion from 'Test<Test<Test<int> > >' to 'Other'`, that shows the types are preserved.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed i would like to stay with compiled time resolution. I thought also that loop with template metaprogramming should be a good solution.

Comment: Very interesting. I will try that and update the code if I succeed to compile it. What can I do If I want instead the loop several lines of expression like a=a+b then c= d+e etc... vector=previous + f. Aim is to have a language where I write only expression and only the operator= on vector makes the inspection graph. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the question, especially with regards to the example expressions given.