# Should we always use auto&& for local variable

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

After reading this thread [`auto&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us), does it mean that we should always use `auto&&` instead of `auto` when we declare a local variable to capture the return type of a function (to exactly preserve the type returned by the function) ?

Use cases could be for instance

```
auto&& result = func_returning_lvalue_or_lvalue_reference();
```

or

```
auto&& iterator = vector_.begin();
```

or anything else.

In other terms it is normal to have a base code with a lot of `auto&&` ?

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13242177/2589776) in that thread gave enough info already. The answer will be yes if you want to accept any initializer regardless of whether it is an lvalue or rvalue expression and its constness.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: and why not using decltype(auto) instead?

Comment: *"we should always use `auto&&`"* In C++, always do something type rules are very suspicious. [Xeo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13235843/341970) gives you good advice on using `auto&&`: "I use `auto&&` in generic code when I need a *modifyable* variable. [...]" I am voting to close this question because this also answers your question in my opinion.

Comment: Strictly speaking not an exact duplicate of [What does auto&& tell us?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us) but Xeo's answer, in my opinion, also answers this question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** It will sometimes lead to undefined behavior.

```
void f()
{
    string a{"a"};
    string b{"b"};
    auto&& c = move(a+b);
    ...
}
```

c will outlive the temporary produced by a+b. There are other ways to hit this issue also.

Answer (score 6):

**No.** You should not use `auto&&` all the time. In particular, you shouldn't use it, if you need a copy. With `auto&&` you might get a copy (as a reference to a temporary object), or you might just get a reference to the original object.

For example:

```
auto&& name = customer.get_name(); // std::string or const std::string&
name.erase(name.find(' '));
```

Does this code compile? And if it compiles, does it change the name of the customer, or does it only work on a temporary object? You can't tell without looking at the signature of the function `get_name()`.