# What's the difference between & and && in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, reference, rvalue-reference

I'm wondering what's the difference between `for (auto& i : v)` and `for (auto&& i : v)` in a range-based for loop like in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << "Initial values: ";

    for (auto i : v)    // Prints the initial values
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto i : v)    // Doesn't modify v because i is a copy of each value
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto& i : v)   // Modifies v because i is a reference
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto&& i : v)  // Modifies v because i is a rvalue reference (Am I right?)
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &i : v) // Wouldn't compile without the /**/ because i is const
        std::cout << /*++*/i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

The output:

> Initial values: 0 1 2 3 4 5
>   1 2 3 4 5 6
>   1 2 3 4 5 6
>   2 3 4 5 6 7
>   2 3 4 5 6 7

Both **seem** to do the same thing here but I'd like to know what's the difference between `for (auto& i : v)` and `for (auto&& i : v)` in this code.

Comment: `auto` uses template argument deduction rules. So `auto` by itself deduces the type by value, `auto&` deduces by reference, and `auto&&` is not an rvalue reference but rather uses reference collapsing rules to deduce the type.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for your answer. I got the "deduces the type by value" part but what does deduce by reference means? Is there something about that I can read that can help me understand it?

Comment: Simply put, `auto&` is an lvalue-reference so it requires an lvalue for its initializer.  The elements of the vector can be iterated over as lvalues, so it works. It's also useful when you want to prevent copying each element. This video should explain everything else - https://vimeo.com/97344493

Comment: @0x499602D2 Okay. This is what I think I got: using only `auto` would copy the object to `i` (already knew this one). And there's no difference between `&` and `&&` in this case because there aren't `rvalue`s, only `lvalue`s. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But if the elements being iterated are rvalues, `auto` by itself will allow a move. And it can only bind to `auto&&` because rvalues cannot bind to lvalue-references.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks. Also, how could possibly the elements being iterated be rvalues? Maybe a `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 PS: Also, you could (and should) post this as an answer.

Comment: @LHLaurini `std::vector<bool>` is the most notorious example.

Comment: You need a special kind of iterator like what `std::vector<bool>` has. It can't just be done automatically, even if you do `for (auto& x : {1, 2, 3})` the elements are still iterated over as lvalues.

Comment: Ah. So the mysterious and unique phrase on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for, "deduction to forwarding reference," just means reference collapsing rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

7 years after I asked this question, I feel qualified to provide a more complete answer.

I'll start by saying that the code I chose back then is not ideal for the purpose of the  question. That's because there is no difference between `&` and `&&` for the example.

Here's the thing: both

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto& i : v)
{
    std::cout << ++i << ' ';
}

std::cout << '\n';
```

and

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (auto&& i : v)
{
    std::cout << ++i << ' ';
}

std::cout << '\n';
```

are equivalent.

Here's proof:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v;

void f()
{
    for (auto& i : v)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), int&>::value);
    }

    for (auto&& i : v)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), int&>::value);
    }
}
```

But why?

Like David G said in the comments, a rvalue reference to a lvalue reference becomes a lvalue reference due to [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), eg

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
using T1 = int&;
using T2 = T1&&;
static_assert(std::is_same<T1, T2>::value);
```

Note that this, however, is different:

```cpp
for (int&& i : v)
{
    // ...
}
```

and will fail, since a rvalue reference can't bind to a lvalue. Reference collapsing doesn't apply to this case, since there is no type deduction.

**TLDR:** for the standard containers, the difference between `&` and `&&` in a range-based for loop is:

- `value_type&` is valid
- `value_type&&` is not valid
- Both `auto&` and `auto&&` are equivalent to `value_type&`

---

Now let's try the opposite: an iterable object that returns rvalues.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Generated
{
    int operator*() const
    {
        return i;
    }

    Generated& operator++()
    {
        ++i;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Generated& x) const
    {
        return i != x.i;
    }

    int i;
};

struct Generator
{
    Generated begin() const { return { 0 }; }
    Generated end() const { return { 6 }; }
};

int main()
{
    Generator g;

    for (const auto& i : g)
    {
        std::cout << /*++*/i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto&& i : g)
    {
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Here, `auto&` doesn't work, since you can't bind a non-const lvalue to a rvalue.

Now we actually have `const int&` and `int&&`:

```cpp
Generator g;

for (const auto& i : g)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), const int&>::value);        
}

for (auto&& i : g)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), int&&>::value); 
}
```

Comment: (This answer seems great but still trying to understand..) Just for future reference: **1)** See [§8.6.4 The range-based for statement] of C++20 standard to understand how range-based for loop works internally. **2)** See @DavidG's comment mentioning 'deduction'. Another example relating deduction(from comments in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242177/10027592)): `int i; auto&& j=i;` is compiled because `auto&&` is **deduced** to be an `int&` (lvalue reference) when assigned an lvalue. (`auto&&` does not become `int&&` because an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue).

Comment: "Both `auto&` and `auto&&` are equivalent to `value_type&`" ->Does this also applies to *structured binding* in a range-based for loop? I.e., `for (auto& [k,v] : mymap){...}` and `for (auto&& [k,v] : mymap){...}` are the same?

Comment: @starriet I don't see why it wouldn't: https://godbolt.org/z/ebG1Wq61r