# what is difference b/w - "for(auto &i : v)" and "for(auto &&i : v)" in cpp?

Tags: c++, cp

what is difference b/w - `for(auto &i : v)`  and `for(auto &&i : v)` in cpp ?

I tried to figure it out but I was getting all results simular only so I am just curious to know that both are same or have any difference..

Comment: It depends on `v`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Better dupe: [What's the difference between & and && in a range-based for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320575/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-a-range-based-for-loop)