# In C++, how can one move each element one to the right using only pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

for example, this array for example, [1,2,3,4,5] would become this array [5,1,2,3,4]

this is what I have come up with, but it does not work:

```
 int  *ptr = arr; //initialize to first element
    int  *ptr2 = arr+1; //initialize it to second element

   while (n >0) // keep doing it until size is done with
   {
       *ptr2 = *ptr; 
       ++ptr2;
       ptr ++;
       n--;//
   }
```

Comment: What is `n` in your code?

Comment: Are you required to have the result in `array` itself? Also, do you have space allocated after the last element in `array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"using only pointers"* is a pretty vague requirement. The following, modern solution in a certain way also uses "only pointers", because `std::rotate` operates on iterators and pointers *are* iterators:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::rotate(begin(arr), end(arr) - 1, end(arr));

    for (auto&& element : arr)
    {
        std::cout << element << "\n";
    }
}
```

Yet I feel that the teacher who gave you this assignment would not be happy with it for some reason. As for your solution:

> ```
>  int  *ptr = arr; //initialize to first element
>     int  *ptr2 = arr+1; //initialize it to second element
>
>    while (n >0) // keep doing it until size is done with
>    {
>        *ptr2 = *ptr; 
>        ++ptr2;
>        ptr ++;
>        n--;//
>    }
> ```

*(I will assume that your `n` is 4 before the loops begins, because otherwise you will have more than 4 iterations and run into undefined behaviour in the last one.)*

In the first iteration of the loop:

- `arr[1]` becomes `arr[0]`.
- `ptr2` is made to point to `arr[2]`.
- `ptr` is made to point to `arr[1]`.

Array after first iteration: **`[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]`**

As you can see, at this point, the element containing value 2 is already lost.

In the second iteration of the loop:

- `arr[2]` becomes `arr[1]`.
- `ptr2` is made to point to `arr[3]`.
- `ptr` is made to point to `arr[2]`.

Array after second iteration: **`[1, 1, 1, 4, 5]`**

Now the element containing value 3 is also lost. The pattern is now clear; you are "losing" all elements and are simply overwriting everything with 1s.

You must find a way to conserve the elements you are overwriting. Or preferably just use `std::rotate`.

Comment: Why the `&&` in `auto&&`? Shouldn't a plain `auto` suffice?

Comment: @zenith: To be honest, I'm still in the process of self-discovery with C++11 `auto` best practices. My current opinion is that `auto&&` is best practice in range-based for loops, and that opinion was influenced by SO discussions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops/13130795. But I am really missing the many years of C++11 experience that would IMO be necessary to be really sure.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us) is also interesting reading. It should be `const auto&&` though. Interestingly enough, while `const auto&` would bind to an rvalue  (`const&` won't) you get better performance in certain situations and probably better clarity by using the one intended for rvalues.

Answer (score 3):

At `*ptr2 = *ptr;` you have lost the information about the initial value of the second element.

I hope that gives you an idea why your current approach can't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `n` is the size of the array. If so, you can use the following code:

```
int tmp = arr[n - 1];          /* Store the last element in `tmp` */

for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) /* Loop backwards */
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];       /* Move all elements up */

arr[0] = tmp;                  /* Insert the last element at the first location */
```

Comment: Note that if `n` is 5, then the OP's original code will have UB due to `ptr2` pointing outside the array's bounds in the last loop iteration.