# How can one move each element in an array in c++ one to the right using only pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays

for example, [1,2,3,4,5] would become [5,1,2,3,4]

I cannot use an extra array and have to only use traversal by index. I can also use ints to store values, but that does not seem to help.

this is my attempt that does not work:

```
void shiftonetoright(int arr[], int n){

    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int s1;

    while(n>0)
    {
        ptr1++;
        s1 =*ptr1;
        *ptr1 =s1;

        n--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::rotate(arr, arr + 1, arr + n)`.

Comment: Is this significantly different from your previous question (with an accepted answer)? By the way `s1 =*ptr1; *ptr1 =s1;` in your code doesn't make much sense...

Comment: [`std::rotate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) is indeed the way to go. Also, you might find Sean Parent's [C++ Seasoning](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) talk particularly informative on this topic ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB OP said he had to use a pointer

Comment: @PaulEvans: That's fine, `arr`, `arr + 1` and `arr + n` are all pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
void shiftonetoright(int arr[], int n)
{

    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int s1 = ptr1[0];
    int s2;

    for(int i = 1  ; i < n ; ++i)
    {
      s2 = ptr1[i];
      ptr1[i] = s1;
      s1 =  s2;
    }

    ptr1[0] = s1;

}
```

Comment: Ooopss... too many same ans....

Answer (score 1):

You've got to rotate the last element back to the beginning and simple shift the other elements, so some thing more like (assuming `n` is the number of elements in `arr`):

```
 void shiftonetoright(int arr[], int n) {
    int last = arr[n - 1];
    int* ptr = arr;
    for( int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) {
         *(ptr + i) = *(ptr + i - 1);
    }
    *ptr = last;
}
```

Comment: The OP was [given essentially this same code 9 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33064149/445976).

Comment: @Blastfurnace ah, didn't know that...

Comment: It's still a good answer, the OP is just being weird.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks, but... a weird c++ programmer -- what next? :P