# Rule of thumb for using auto&& and const auto &

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto, forwarding-reference

I have studied `auto` and I know it deduces types from initialized values. If I tried to write some guidelines for usage of `auto`, can I put below statements as rules?

1. Use `auto &&` for all values (r-values and l-value, as it is an universal ref) that are modifiable,
2. `auto &&` even for read only values,
3. Use `auto` wherever possible  (individual preference for coding style).

**EDIT**

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(const Test&) = default;
    Test(Test&&) = default;

    int i = 1;
};

Test getObj()
{
    return Test();
}

Test& getObjByRef()
{
    static Test tobj;
    return tobj;    
}

const Test getObjConst()
{
    return Test();
}

int main()
{
    auto && obj1 = getObj();
    obj1.i = 2;

    std::cout << " getObj returns: " << getObj().i << std::endl;

    auto&& obj2 = getObjByRef();
    obj2.i = 3;

    std::cout << " getObjByRef returns: " << getObjByRef().i << std::endl;

    auto && obj3 = getObjConst();

    //obj3.i = 4;  => //Error   C3490   'i' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object

    return 0;
}
```

So in above example i used `auto &&` for all three functions

- `getObj`
- `getObjByRef`
- `getObjConst`

and it works as expected.
Now can I **conclude** that:

- `auto &&` can be used to hold(initialize) any value, **OR**
- We can use `auto &&` every possible place.

*Do you see any pitfall of this approach?*

Comment: Don't use auto&&. Use either plain type or const reference. Unless you implement move ctor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13242177/2352671

Comment: N.B. it's called a forwarding reference now, not a universal reference.

Comment: @user3104201 if we use plain type, it will invoke copy constructor. for const reference, it is always const.  
 Even without move constructor we can have auto && isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely yeah standard says it like that way.

Comment: good if ppl tell  why they are down voting. It may be helpful for improvement.

Comment: What makes you think r-value reference, move semantics, forwarding references etc. - have to do with `auto`, `const` and references ?

Comment: @Ajay where he is saying that auto has to do something with rvalue reference or move semantics, he is just mentioning that auto&& is forwarding reference

Comment: Now what we can debate is whether auto&& is good to use for all scenarios, one scenario where i find useful is we can use auto&& to iterate over locally declared vector(lvalue) or vector returned from function(rvalue)

Comment: can anyone suggest scenario where auto&& will create problem

Comment: Also apart from obvious auto advantages like you need to initialize variable,you don't need to use that verbose declaration for things like iterator there are other positives of auto also like portability, check this link where author is describing why we need to use auto for vector size https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/

Answer (score -4):

1) Yes
2) Yes
3) As you said, 'individual preference for coding style'

Comment: Could you explain your answers? I think the questioner is looking for an argumentation for or against his suggested guidelines.

Comment: @jotrocken 1) 'auto&&' is universal reference, can be bind to both l- and r- value. I wouldn't use it always, but it's certainly possible. 2) 'const auto&' is read only reference, you can only use const methods on such object. 3) it's up to developer if he/she wants to use auto and let compiler deduce type or write down type on your own. OP asked if those statements are true.

Comment: @paweldac as for 1) you said, you would not use it always, so do u find any shortcoming which prevents it to be used *always* (except for un-modifiable elements)
  => It is fast then comparable to simple auto.. right?