# How am I able to iterate through a string vector in c++?

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, c-strings

I want to iterate through a string vector in c++. I want to open each item in the list with fopen.

```
const char *filep //fopen needs a constant char pointer.
for (vector<string>::iterator it = filelist.begin(); it != filelist.end(); it++)
{
    filep = (const char *)it; //This isn't working. How can I fix this
    fopen(filep, "rb"); 
}
```

Comment: try `*it` ......

Comment: The really scary thing is that this might have compiled on some compilers, and then only crashed at runtime.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - that's why the use of explicit type conversions (like `(const char *)` in this case) is deemed poor practice in C++ and actively discouraged by quite a few coding guidelines and by experienced developers.    Essentially, such conversions force the compiler to do a conversion that would otherwise be diagnosed as an error.

Answer (score 6):

You should have used `it->c_str()` as `it` is essentially a *pointer* to the element in the `std::vector`. But for an easier life use

```
for (const auto& s : filelist){
    // s is a const reference to an element in filelist
    // use s.c_str() if you need the character buffer
}
```

This is valid from C++11 onwards. Using `const auto&` rather than `auto` obviates a `std::string` copy.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
filep = (const char *)it;
```

to this:

```
filep = it->c_str();
```

---

However, you do extra, unnecessary steps, since you could just do this instead:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = filelist.begin(); it != filelist.end(); it++)
    fopen(it->c_str(), "rb");
```

which reduces the number of lines of your code to just two, and doesn't use an extra pointer.

---

PS: A more modern approach can be found in [Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569197/2411320), or use the [`auto&&` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us).

Comment: But seriously, there's no harm in having similar answers: why not re-introduce yours? SO works best when there are a few answers to choose from.

Comment: @Bathsheba it was like a synopsis of yours, without a const. I will updated to suggest your answer though, I like it more! ;)

Comment: Yeah, it [seems like it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us) ;)

Answer (score 0):

A `std::string` is a type which is completely different from `const char *`. Hence, you need to get underlying `character buffer` stored in string. For that You must use method `std::string::c_str()` or `std::string::data()` whatever you like.

Do it like below (Inspired from other answers now using `range-based for-loop`),

```
const char *filep //fopen needs a constant char pointer.
for (auto & str : filelist)
{
    filep = str.c_str();
    fopen(filep, "rb"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a method getstring in which you will return the string.

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<iterator.size();i++){
cout << iterator[i]->getstring()<<endl;
}
```