# Best practice for const temporary types

Tags: c++, c++14

Suppose I am doing a computation that involves creating a temporary object that I won't modify:

```
auto tmp = val * val;
// Do some calculations with tmp...
```

Further, I do not need `tmp` to be an lvalue since I won't be taking its address.

Under these conditions, which idiom should I be using in my code:

```
1.       auto    tmp = val * val;
2. const auto    tmp = val * val;
3. const auto &  tmp = val * val;
4.       auto && tmp = val * val;
5. const auto && tmp = val * val;
```

Note that I am explicitly leaving off the `auto &` because that will often lead to UB. However, I am aware that the `const auto &` will extend the temp lifetime, so I leave that as an option here.

Unsurprinsgly, for this simple example, `-O3` compiles down to the same code anyway: https://godbolt.org/z/oXj3hd

But in a more complicated example, I would imagine that they don't.

My thinking is that option 3 or 5 are probably the most correct since they will preserve the constness of the object, and because they will hold temporary objects.

EDIT:

A lot of people are mentioning the fact that in this simple example, there will not be a need to even name the temp. That is correct. What I am after is a recommendation for what to do when the expression generating the temp is complicated, and will be used repeatedly in the code.

Comment: How complex is the actual calculation you need? If it's just as simple as `val * val` why can't you use it directly in the final expression (where you would otherwise use `tmp`)?

Comment: Note that you can't move `const` objects.

Comment: You simply should forget about. The compilers are clever enough to remove all the stuff. If you have really a cpu consumtion problem, measure! But you can trust, that never a temporary will rise a problem with every normal compiler! Write readable code instead! Your examples are full of more or less horrible coding examples :-) BTW: "Almost auto" will take you some sleepless nights in the future.

Comment: @Klaus I disagree. There are very real differences between the samples and none of them (except 5.) are horrible. Moveability (or lack thereof) alone can be a strong performance factor.

Comment: I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us where the answers cover this very set of options, but whether it's truly a dupe is questionable (it's a question is about the solution, not the problem).

Comment: And finally, note that the answers to this question do (necessarily) hinge upon `operator*` being used (i.e. a function that returns by value in a sane world). If you wanted to store e.g. the return value of a getter (which might return `const&`), or work in a templated setting where you can't be too sure what you are given from some calculation, things could look different once again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
auto tmp = val * val;
```

Use this when you want to cast `tmp` to an rvalue later on (`std::move(tmp)`).

```
const auto tmp = val * val;
```

Use this when you don't need to `std::move(tmp)` afterwards. Clear, not surprising, honors Scott Meyers Item "Use `const` whenever possible".

```
const auto &  tmp = val * val;
```

Don't do this. It does lifetime extension, but you don't gain anything from that compared to 2., because the object has to live somewhere anyhow. When `val*val` returns an object by value, you won't copy it with 2. due to (N)RVO (assuming that `operator *` for `val` objects behaves sanely), so `const auto& tmp` and `const auto tmp` will both refer to an object within the stack of your scope.

```
auto && tmp = val * val;
const auto && tmp = val * val;
```

Doesn't yield any performance benefits, but complicates reading of the code. Don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you bind a reference to `val * val` ? Performance aside, I would consider this as obfuscation.

> Unsurprinsgly, for this simple example, -O3 compiles down to the same code anyway:

Yes, no big surprise here. So just use the most concise and least contrived. `const` is not for performance and the compiler is clever enough to realize that the variable isnt modified without your help, though `const` documents the constness for you and thus adds to readability. Hence

```
const auto tmp = val * val;
```

Anything else is turning something simple into something unnecessarily complicated.

Last but not least, consider if you need the temporary at all, or if you can simply write `val*val` in place of `tmp`. On the other hand, if you use `tmp` many times, it is of course worth to give it a meaningful name (meaningful = something more meaningful than `tmp` ;)

PS: Note that `const` prevents moving from `tmp`, which might be a downside on performance. However, in general when worried about performance you should first write readable code and only then measure for performance.

Comment: `const` is good for value semantics and documenting immutability, but kills move semantics. Really depends on the underlying type whether you should prefer one or the other.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes I saw your comment and it is an issue to be considered, though never thought about it before and have to do some reading before I could "fix" the answer. For now I just added a "dont do premature optimization" note

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific and actual performance issue (in which case you need to profile and measure how your program performs), there is no point to ask which option is best at the assembly level.

However, one is more explicit and less surprising:

```
const auto    tmp = val * val;
```

Use it unless you can prove it has lesser performance and it matters in the global observable behaviour of your program.