# Can we use "do" for a "for" loop?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, loops, for-loop

[image]

As seen above, the algorithm uses **"do"** after **"For"**. I am aware this is only a pseudo-algorithm but is this theoretically okay?

I am not willing to share the entire algorithm as **it is not my work**.

Comment: Firstly, a pseudo-algorithm should be language independent, follow whatever convention is followed by existing papers. Secondly, this question is more suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Python and C++ have very little in common besides both of them being programming languages. Is **what** theoretically okay? In code like that "do" is just a word meaning "do the stuff listed right below here". Some programming languages have a `do` keyword, like Bash or Ruby, while many don't.

Comment: you need to share full picture, snippet of it won't provide you a good solution

Comment: Strange question, pseudo code doesn't have a *theory* that's what makes it pseudo code.

Answer (score 3):

In code like that "do" is just a word meaning "do the stuff listed right below here". Some programming languages have a `do` keyword, like Bash or Ruby, while many don't.

In Python:

```py
for e in edges:
  # ...
```

In C++:

```cpp
for (auto&& e : edges) {
  // ...
}
```

Neither of them uses `do`.

For contrast, Ruby uses `do` to define blocks, akin to `function(e) { ... }` in JavaScript:

```rb
edges.each do |e|
  # ...
end
```

And Bash where it's a necessary element of the loop:

```sh
for edge in $(edges); do
  # ...
done
```

The notation you're seeing there is just a convention used quite often in computer science, but it's basically just an English explanation.

Comment: Can you explain the use of `auto&&` in the iterative for loop in C++? I know that `&` is supposed to indicate a reference, but what does `&&` indicate?

Comment: It's a C++-ism meaning ["just give me a reference to the thing, whatever it is, preserving `const`-ness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us) where `auto&` means "give me a mutable reference" normally, so you often need to specify `const auto&` which can be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this mathematical algorithm the "do" does not mean the same as in the syntax of a programming language.
In C++ this "do" will be not the `do { /* ... */ } while ()`  construct, but simply the brackets after the for:  `for (/* edges e_wi */) { /* algorithm */ }`.

That is, "do" in mathematics is just a syntactical construct that means "this is the body".
So, you can't use "do" after a "for" loop.