# What is the life time of a in "auto&& a= f();" where f() returns an object by value?

Tags: c++, lifetime, rvalue-reference, type-deduction, forwarding-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {};

A f() { return A(); }

int main() {
    auto &&a = f();
    std::cout << typeid(f()).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(A{}).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
1A
1A
1A
```

Questions are,

1. what does `1A` mean here? (GCC on a linux box)
2. `auto &&` should be a forwarding reference, and in this case since `f()` returns an `A` object by value, `a` should be deduced to rvalue reference, correct?
3. If `a` is indeed rvalue reference, and since a (temporary) rvalue's lifetime could only be extended by a const lvalue ref, `a` should go out of scope right after this line, is that correct?

**Edit**: Fixed the most vexing problem in the last `cout` statement, as many pointed out.

**Summary** of the great answers, for posterity:

1. `1A` is internal representation of type `A`, by Guillaume Racicot. And `F1AvE` indicates a Function style cast in typeid(A()) resulting in a prvalue, by Ted Lyngmo.
2. turns out `typeid()` is not the tool to check reference, as it gives the referenced end type. Ted Lyngmo gave the right way to do it, and yes it is an r-value reference.

```
static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(a)>); // like this, ...
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), A&&>);        // or like this
```

3. Richard Critten gave the link that says ["The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11)..."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime).

Comment: Just add ctor/dtor pair that prints something so you can verify the lifetime.

Comment: `1A` is an `A` type, and `F1AvE` is an `A()` constructor.

Comment: _"...The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an __rvalue reference (since C++11)__, see reference initialization for details...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime    So the lifetime of the temporary returned from `f()` is extended to be the same as the life time of `a`.

Comment: @Eljay `A()` is declaration of function which takes no argument and return A.

Comment: @rafix • I was speaking of `F1AvE`.

Comment: @Eljay Me too, check `std::cout << typeid(A{}).name() << std::endl;` what is printed ? A() doesnt mean ctor in this context.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us

Comment: @rafix • ahh, I think `F1AvE` is the result of the *most vexing parse*.

Comment: Try piping the output to `c++filt` to demangle the typeid names.

Comment: Please don't change your question after an answer is posted. This is confusing to future readers.

Comment: A reference to an rvalue is an lvalue. The type of a is A&& (auto deduces to A), and a is an lvalue. I think you confuse rvalue with rvalue reference.

Comment: @Richard Critten, this is quite helpful, thanks!

Comment: @mfnx A bit of nitpicking. You're talking about two different `a`s here. The one that is an expression is an lvalue, but it's type is `A`, [not `A &&`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). The other one is a variable of type `A &&`, but it's not an lvalue per se, because only expressions have value categories.

Comment: Oups ... I just noticed that the question has changed while I wrote and tried to improve on my answer. The thing I found most interesting (the `typeid(A())`) is now gone? Hmm, I noticed that there were updates but didn't refresh the screen because I didn't expect _that_ much to change.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes.. what I wanted to ask originally was not actually about that part, but nonetheless learned a lot from your answer, thanks!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat just saw this, ok..

Comment: @rafix07 • I realized that `typeid(A())` is much like `std::function<A()>`, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does `1A` mean here? (GCC on a linux box)

It means that the length of the name is `1` followed by the letter. There are many rules on how to mangle a type, but it encodes its namespace, template parameter value and other things.

> `auto &&` should be a forwarding reference, and in this case since f() returns an A object by value, a should be deduced to rvalue reference, correct?

The `typeid` operator discards all top level cv and ref qualifiers.

Also, it see through references and returns the type info for the refered type instead.

From the [typeid operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) page:

> If type is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the referenced type.

But yes, the type deduced is `A`, so you are declaring `A&&`. But even if `a` is an rvalue reference, the expression `a` is an lvalue.

> If a is indeed rvalue reference, and since a (temporary) rvalue's lifetime could only be extended by a const lvalue ref, a should go out of scope right after this line, is that correct?

The lifetime end at the end of the scope, per the lifetime extension rules.

---

Now for why the typeid is different.

This is not about rvalue or forwarding references. This is the most vexing parse problem. `A()` is a function that returns `A` and has no parameters.

Use `{}` for initialization and you'll see the problem disappear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {};

A f() { return A(); }

int main() {
    auto &&a = f();
    std::cout << typeid(f()).name() << std::endl; // 1A
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;   // 1A
    std::cout << typeid(A{}).name() << std::endl; // 1A
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Racicot thanks, didn't expect that but just learned something new! I'll fix that, but the question was not originated from the fact that the third line prints differently. I think you are a few steps ahead of me. On a side note, `typeid(A())` hits the 'most vexing problem', but `return A()` does not, why?

Comment: @QnA because you cannot declare types in a return expression, but `typeid` works with both. You can desambiguate it with an extra pair of parens, that will force it to evaluate to an expression instead: `(A())`

Answer (score 1):

1. `lA` is the internal name for an `A` and "*If* type *is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type.*" - and `a` is a reference type.
   `F1AvE` indicates a Function style cast in `typeid(A())` resulting in a [*prvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). You can compare with something more familiar, like `int()`, where the `typeid::name()` is changed to `i` from `lA`:

   ```
   std::cout << typeid(int()).name() << std::endl;  // FivE
   std::cout << typeid(A()).name() << std::endl;    // F1AvE 

   std::cout << typeid(int{}).name() << std::endl;  // i
   std::cout << typeid(A{}).name() << std::endl;    // 1A
   ```

   [Explicit cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) `new_type ( )`:

   > If *new_type* names a non-array complete object type, this expression is an prvalue of type *new_type*, *designating a temporary (until C++17)* / *whose result object is (possibly with added cv-qualifiers) (since C++17)* of that type. If *new_type* is an object type, the object is value-initialized.
2. Yes, as seen here:

   ```
   static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(a)>); // like this, ...
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), A&&>);        // or like this
   ```
3. Its lifetime will not end at the end of the full expression but at the end of the enclosing block.