# C++11 std::forward_as_tuple and std::forward

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, perfect-forwarding

Should I `std::forward` my function parameters when I use them as arguments to `std::forward_as_tuple`?

```
template<class ... List>
void fn(List&& ... list){
   // do I need this forward?
   call_fn( forward_as_tuple( forward<List>(list)... ) );  
}
```

I know that they will be stored as rvalue references, but is there anything else I should consider?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must use `std::forward` in order to preserve the value category of the argument(s) to `fn()`. Since the arguments have a name within `fn`, they are lvalues, and without `std::forward` they will always be passed as such to `std::forward_as_tuple`.

The difference can be demonstrated using the [following example](http://ideone.com/yYvNNP):

```
template<typename T>
void bar2(T&& t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' '
               << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void bar1(T&& t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' '
              << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << '\n';
    bar2(std::forward<T>(t));
    bar2(t);
}
```

`bar1` always passes it arguments on to `bar2`, once with `std::forward` and once without. Now let's call them with an lvalue and an rvalue argument.

```
foo f;
bar1(f);
std::cout << "--------\n";
bar1(foo{});
```

Output:

```
void bar1(T&&) [with T = foo&] 0
void bar2(T&&) [with T = foo&] 0
void bar2(T&&) [with T = foo&] 0
--------
void bar1(T&&) [with T = foo] 1
void bar2(T&&) [with T = foo] 1
void bar2(T&&) [with T = foo&] 0
```

As you can see from the output, in both cases, without the use of `std::forward`, the argument is being passed as an lvalue to `bar2`.

Comment: What would `call_fn(std::forward_as_tuple<List...>(list...));` do?

Comment: @LogicStuff I don't think that will compile. Say the pack has a single type, `T`. Now, if an rvalue `T` was passed to the outer `fn`, then `List` would be deduced as `T`, so you'd be writing `call_fn(std::forward_as_tuple<T>(t));`. But `forward_as_tuple` would then want an rvalue reference to `t` as its argument. It does work the same if you pass `fn` an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you almost certainly do want to use `std::forward` here, this is assuming that the arguments in `list` are not used after the called to `call_fn`. **This is a typical use case of `std::forward`, in that you want to exercise the semantics of perfect forwarding**.

`std::forward` **[preserves the value category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8526598/3747990) of its arguments** (i.e. lvalues as lvalues, rvalues as rvalues). `std::forward_as_tuple` in turn will do the same, as if `std::tuple<List&&...>(std::forward<List>(list)...)` had been called.

A note on the "stored as rvalue references". It is not that the arguments `List` in the parameter pack are all rvalues references (they could be), but the `List` is being deduced in this context, hence reference collapsing will apply and the deduced type(s) could be rvalue references or lvalue references. During the creation of the `std::tuple`, it is this distinction that you would want to maintain/preserve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to preserve the perfect forwarding semantics. In your example:

```
template<class ... List>
void fn(List&& ... list)
```

the type `List&&`, where `List` is actually a template parameter, is a [Universal Reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) rather than an r-value reference. As such, you should `std::forward` them to `std::forward_as_tuple` function, otherwise inside the `std::forward_as_tuple` the r-value references passed to `fn` will be visible as l-value references due to reference collapsing.