# Forwarding Arguments using std::forward_as_tuple and std::tuple_cat

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

See here for sample code: https://godbolt.org/z/o5osbq3bY

Hi everyone,

I'm working on some code that pulls values from a virtual machine. The interface requires both the type of the value and its index on the stack, which I've mocked into `T get_one(int stack_pos)`.
I'm writing a wrapper that will pull `N` values from the stack and pushes to a C++ function.

In the sample, if you define `I_LOVE_RVALUES`, the code uses `std::forward_as_tuple`
Otherwise, it'll use `std::make_tuple`.
I want to forward the values from the VM to the C++ function with as little overhead as possible,
so at first I tried with the pass-by-rvalue. However, I'm getting corrupted values.

Following the advice of this thread: [C++11 std::forward_as_tuple and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427938/c11-stdforward-as-tuple-and-stdforward) I've thrown `std::forward`'s everywhere, but it still doesnt work

I've switched to the pass by value version now and it works fine, but I want to understand why the Rvalue version doesn't work. My understanding is that I followed all the rules:

1. Each rvalue is either used or forwarded into another Rvalue reference
2. The tuple is only passed into `std::apply` and never used again, so its rvalues can be consumed.

My best guess is there's some interaction between the Rvalue-tuples and `std::tuple_cat`, but I don't really understand what's going on.

### Full sample code listing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <cxxabi.h>

#define I_LOVE_RVALUES

#ifdef I_LOVE_RVALUES
#define tuple_creator std::forward_as_tuple
#else
#define tuple_creator std::make_tuple
#endif


template<typename T>
T get_one(int stack_pos)
{
    // std::cout << typeid(T).name() + std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
    return static_cast<T>(stack_pos);
}

template<typename T>
inline auto get_all(int i)
{
    return tuple_creator(std::forward<T>(get_one<T>(i)));
}
// recursive case
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename ...T>
inline auto get_all(int i)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(
        tuple_creator(std::forward<T0>(get_one<T0>(i))),
        get_all<T1, T...>(i+1)
    );
}

void print_all(int i, float f1, float f2)
{
    std::cout << i << f1 << f2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto&& tup = get_all<int, float, float>(0);
    std::string tup_typeid_name = typeid(decltype(tup)).name();
    std::apply(print_all, tup);
    // here i'll make my forward_as_tuple directly
    std::apply(print_all, std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(0), std::move(1), std::move(2)));
    std::cout << tup_typeid_name << std::endl;
}
```

If `I_LOVE_RVALUES` is defined, the first line is garbage. Otherwise, it should read `012`

The second line should always read `012`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Could you please also include the code in your question?

Comment: Its in the godbolt link but I can include it inline

Comment: Please do so.  If the link ever dies, how could anyone help you?

Comment: Using Clang15 on MacOS I get the correct values either way. What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: @RandomBits gcc11 on linux on my host computer. The godbolt linked above changed to clang 15 on x64 also has the same garbage values as gcc11

Comment: @saltyJeff I am on arm64, so that might be changing my results.

Answer (score 0):

`get_one` returns a prvalue. To pass that to `forward_as_tuple`, a temporary object is created and then the resulting tuple refers to that temporary. But that temporary is going to be destroyed at the end of the full-expression containing the call - in your case, as soon as `get_all` returns.

In the end, `forward_as_tuple` produces a tuple of references, but the things referred to still have to be stored *somewhere*.

Comment: Why does get_all destroy the temporary? The call stack looks like this:

1. auto&& tup  in main() is an rvalue

2. get_all uses tuple_cat, which takes in tuples as an rvalue

3. the tuples passed into tuple_cat use forwarding to construct each element, which preserves rvalue semantics

At what point does the rvalue stop prolonging the lifetimes?