# Can someone help me enlighten this template?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I know that the title sucks, it's just that I wasn't really sure how else to ask this, because I'm lacking knowledge in many basic C++ features and I'm trying to address them one by one.

So I'm starting to dive into C++ templates. For now I'm building really basic ones, simply to help me debug my code, like:

```
    void printVectors(const T& vec, const S& vec2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            print("------------");
            printNoEndln(vec[i]);
            printNoEndln("->");
            print(vec2[i]);
        }
    }
```

Now, starting with SDL, I came across something like this:

```
    template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
    T& AddComponent(TArgs&&... args) {
        T* newComponent(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
        newComponent->componentName = typeid(T).name();
        newComponent->owner = this;
        components.emplace_back(newComponent);
        newComponent->Init();
        return *newComponent;
    }
```

So I'm going to describe what I understand by this line by line, and I'd be really glad if you guys could correct me.

1- Creating a template of type T with N arguments (Thats what the spread operator means here, right? It declares a variadic template?)

2- Declaring a function `AddComponent` that returns the reference of T and receiving N references of references of the type TArgs (???) (This part is really confusing to me).

3- Declaring a pointer T to a new object of type T in a very strange way. For starters, I don't understand why the instantiation of `newComponent` is being addressed with `()` such as `newComponent()` instead of `T* newComponent = new Component(...)`(Seriously, that is all that I can grasp from this line)

From line 4 and forward the code is very simple to me and needs no explanation whatsoever.

From what I could understand, my gap is not being able to understand: variadic templates and functions, rvalues, lvalues and the forward problem. Is that correct? Can you guys point me to useful articles regarding these topics? I find most of cpp references very formal and way beyond my league. It's funny how I can read C#, Java, Typescript and Javascript documentations with no problem but when it comes to C++ it gets really tough to extract something from the documentations. I usually just skip the formality to the actual example code and then I try it out myself on the compiler to understand what is happening.

I know it's a lot, answer with whatever information you judge useful.

Thanks guys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8526598/1870760 does this answer the `std::forward`?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11) for more information about declaring rvalue-references (`&&`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
T& AddComponent(TArgs&&... args)
```

That's a declaration of a function template `AddComponent`.
`T` and `TArgs` are template arguments, both of which must be types. `TArgs` is a variadic argument (can hold 0 or more types). A [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) stamps out functions for each unique combination of `T` and `TArgs`, for ex. `AddComponent<int,long,float>` could be such a function.

`TArgs&&...` are called [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) because `&&` inside a template declaration has an effect of preserving the value category (lvalue/rvalue) of the argument(s).

```
    T* newComponent(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
```

That's a definition of a local variable `newComponent` of type pointer-to-`T` and initial value `new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)`.

[`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is a helper utility that works together with `TArgs&&` and when needed passes rvalue references through to the call. When browsing code you can ignore it and read `new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)` as `new T(args...)`. Now that is a variadic [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) syntax; here the arguments `args` from the template are simply passed to `new()`.

For more details refer to your favorite [C++ Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). My favorite (years ago) was *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers (Scott calls forwarding references *universal references*, for the rest is a great book).

Comment: Thank you so much for the taking the time! Everything is almost cristal clear now! I just still can't understand this declaration of the local variable associated with the pointer-to-T.

Why are we "calling" `newComponent` to define its initial value? Does this syntax only happens inside a template? I couldn't really reproduce it outside of the template scope.

Comment: That's direct initialization, the oldest syntax in C++. `int i(5);` is another example. It's not recommended because it can lead to the infamous most vexing parse.  Modern C++ alternative syntax is `int i{5};`