# Creating function to read variables from file into variable quantity of parameters

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

How would I create a function that can read values from a file into multiple numbers of variables varying from 1 to many?

Here's what I have so far, working from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion).

Note: I cannot use fold expressions (`file >> ... >>> x`) because the code uses C++ 14.

test_stream_file Contents:

```
teststring_a    teststring_b
```

Code:

```
template<typename... Args>
void fileread(std::fstream& file, Args...args)
{
    using expander = int[];
    expander{ (file >> (std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
}

int main() {

    std::fstream teststream;
    teststream.open("test_stream_file", std::ios::in);
    std::string a, b;

    fileread(teststream, a, b);
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

When I run this I get error C2679: "binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right hand operator of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)". I'm a bit lost here.  I read the documentation and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526598/how-does-stdforward-work) on std::forward but am still not seeing what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to explain why, but you are missing universal reference on `Args` - it should be `Args&&... args)`: https://godbolt.org/z/GGao57YK9. I though your version  (without `&&`) gets arguments by copy, but compiler states it's an r-value: https://godbolt.org/z/n5bKbq3dP

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for you:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

template<typename... Args>
void fileread(std::istream& file, Args&...args)
{
    (file>> ...>>args);
}

int main() {

    std::stringstream teststream("hallo welt");
    //teststream.open("test_stream_file", std::ios::in);
    std::string a, b;

    fileread(teststream, a, b);
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

Why do you try to do perfect forwarding, you want to change the variables that are given to you function, so it should be regular references.

Comment: The code I'm working in is the C++ 14 standard so it does not allow fold expressions. I cannot change this unfortunately. Have added this to the question.

Comment: If you can not use fold expressions then you can not use any syntax with "...". If you can not use fold expressions you must implement it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `std::forward` to forward `args` since they must be lvalue references. This should be enough

```
template<typename... Args>
void fileread(std::istream& file, Args&...args)
{
    using expander = int[];
    expander{ ((file >> args), 0)... };
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f6nofE3vj)