# is any difference between std::forward<T> and std::forward<decltype(t)>?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

are these functions equivalent?

```
template <class T>
void foo(T && t)
{
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template <class T>
void foo2(T && t)
{
    bar(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t));
}

template <class T>
void foo3(T && t)
{
    bar(std::forward(t));
}
```

if they are, can I always use this macro for perfect forwarding?

```
#define MY_FORWARD(var) std::forward<decltype(var)>(var)
```

or just use

```
bar(std::forward(t));
```

I believe `foo2` and `foo3` are same, but I found people are always use forward like `foo`, is any reason to explicitly write the type?

I understand that `T` and `T&&` are two different types, but I think `std::forward<T>` and `std::forward<T&&>` always give the same result?

---

Edit:

the reason I want to use macro is I want to save some typing on following C++1y code, I have many similar code in different places

```
#define XLC_FORWARD_CAPTURE(var) var(std::forward<decltype(var)>(var))
#define XLC_MOVE_CAPTURE(var) var(std::move(var))

template <class T, class U>
auto foo(T && func, U && para )
{
    auto val = // some calculation
    return [XLC_FORWARD_CAPTURE(func),
            XLC_FORWARD_CAPTURE(para),
            XLC_MOVE_CAPTURE(val)](){
              // some code use val
              func(std::forward<U>(para)); 
          };
}
```

Comment: @LaszloPapp how can I make inline function version of my macro?

Comment: I think they are the same, but I would not still obfuscate with a macro.

Comment: Right, you changed the comparison to another two functions since the initial version ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779900/why-is-template-argument-deduction-disabled-with-stdforward - the `foo3` you added isn't valid.

Comment: `foo3` is invalid (and for good reason) (see Mat's comment). The use of a macro is valid, but it would mean using a macro, with all the associated problems (in particular: scope insensitivity, and opaqueness to the syntax and type-checking parts of the compiler).

Comment: @Mankarse I believe macro will improve the readability of the code in my case (forward capture and move capture in lambda) if it does not hurt the correctness

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Are these functions **two** equivalent?

**Yes**, they are equivalent. `decltype(t)` is the same as `T&&`, and when used with `std::forward`, there is no difference between `T` and `T&&`, regardless what `T` is.

> Can I always use this macro for perfect forwarding?

Yes, you can. If you want to make your code unreadable and unmaintainable, then do so. But I strongly advise against it. On the one hand, you gain basically nothing from using this macro. And on the other hand, other developers have to take a look at the definition to understand it, and it can result in subtle errors. For example adding additional parentheses won't work:

```
MY_FORWARD((t))
```

In contrast, the form with `decltype` is perfectly valid. In particular, it is the preferred way of forwarding parameters from generic lambda expressions, because there are no explicit type parameters:

```
[](auto&& t) { foobar(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); }
```

---

I ignored the 3rd variant with `std::forward(t)`, because it isn't valid.

---

**Update:** Regarding your example: You can use *call-by-value* instead of *call-by-reference* for the function template `foo`. Then you can use `std::move` instead of `std::forward`. This adds two additional moves to the code, but no additional copy operations. On the other hand, the code becomes much cleaner:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto foo(T func, U para)
{
    auto val = // some calculation
    return [func=std::move(func),para=std::move(para),val=std::move(val)] {
        // some code use val
        func(std::move(para)); 
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks. for the macro part, is any good way to forward/move capture variables in lambda without repeating type the variable name for 3 times? like this `[var(std::forward<decltype(var)>(var))](){}`

Comment: From review: @rtdev made the following suggestion: "The lambda has to be mutable in order to modify (move from) one of it's captures. If it's not mutable, the std::move in the call to func will have no effect. "

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not solve the problem in title completely.

A macro argument preserves the type of the expression. A forwarding parameter in a template does not. This means `t` in `foo2` (as a forwarding function parameter) has the type `T&&` (because this is the forwarding template parameter), but it can be something different when the macro is in other contexts. For example:

```
using T = int;
T a = 42;
T&& t(std::move(a));
foo(MY_FORWARD(t)); // Which foo is instantiated?
```

Note here `t` is *not* an xvalue, [but an lvalue](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#2). With `std::forward<T>(t)`, which is equivalent to `std::forward<int>(t)`, `t` would be forwarded as an lvalue. However, with `MY_FORWARD(t)`, which is equivalent to `std::forward<int&&>(t)`, `t` would be forwarded as an xvalue. This contextual-dependent difference is sometime desired when you have to deal with some declared variables with rvalue reference types (not forwarding paramter even they may look like similar in syntax).