# Macro replacement function for automatic perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, perfect-forwarding

I often use this macro to perfectly forward a parameter without having to know the type of the parameter:

```
#define FORWARD(a) std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)
```

I now want to get rid of the macro and therefore I'm searching for an equivalent definition of a function in c++ which can be used interchangeably with the macro.

This may be a simplistic example, but for the record: I want code like this to compile correctly with arbitrary types for `Param{A,B}` - without having to use the expanded form everywhere (like `std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)`).

```
decltype(auto) operator Op(ParamA a, ParamB b) {
    return Forward(a) Op Forward(b);
}
```

Hint: *Not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321028/is-any-difference-between-stdforwardt-and-stdforwarddecltypet)

Comment: How about forwarding with a [unary `>>`](https://wg21.link/p0644)? :P

Comment: At first I though you were kidding, but actually thats a quite interesting approach! I'd like to see it in c++2a

Comment: Of course, `std::forward` *is* the function for perfect forwarding. That's why we use it. Had it worked anyway, we wouldn't have had that function.

Comment: If this is not a template (that is you know types `ParamA` and `ParamB`) then can't you just live without `std::forward` passing arguments manually?

Comment: Why would I use the macro then? I have to remove that redundancy, even though it seems unnnecessary. It might be just me, but it deeply disturbs me ;)

Comment: Might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779900/why-is-template-argument-deduction-disabled-with-stdforward/8862379#8862379