# Why don't we need to provide template argument type for std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11

Both std::move and std::forward are template functions, why is it that we don't need to provide a template argument type for std::move but std::forward?

For example (from Effective Modern C++):

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(Widget&& rhs)
    : s(std::move(rhs.s)) {} 
...

private:
    std::string s;
};
```

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(Widget&& rhs)
    : s(std::forward<std::string>(rhs.s)) {}
...
};
```

Comment: Hm... @KerrekSB Is your dupe really answering the question? I guess a good answer would explain why template type deduction fails (/ should fail) for `std::forward` but doesn't for `std::move`, which I can't find in the dupe.

Comment: The question you should be asking is why doesn't `std::forward` use template argument deduction, and that is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779900/why-is-template-argument-deduction-disabled-with-stdforward).

Comment: @Praetorian Yeah I agree that that's a good dupe, the only missing piece would be why `std::move` is *different* in that point, which is ok if one knows that template type deduction exists in the first place.

Comment: @leemes: Hm, maybe, but that should still mean that the other question should get improved or new answers, so we don't spread this out so much. Well, I don't mind, if someone wants to reopen this, go ahead.