# C2516 Error in inheriting from a lambda in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class OnExitImpl : private T
{
public:
    template <typename Y>
    OnExitImpl(Y&& todo) : T(std::forward<Y>(todo)), _doIt(true) {}

    OnExitImpl(OnExitImpl&& other) : T(std::move(static_cast<T&>(other))), _doIt(other._doIt)
    {
        other._doIt = false;
    }

    ~OnExitImpl()
    {
        if (_doIt)
        {
            (*this)();
        }
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        _doIt = false;
    }

    OnExitImpl& operator=(OnExitImpl&& other)
    {
        this->T::operator=(std::move(static_cast<T&>(other)));
        _doIt = other._doIt;
        other._doIt = false;
    }

private:
    bool _doIt;
};

template <typename T>
OnExitImpl<T> OnExit(T action)
{
    return OnExitImpl<T>(std::move(action));
}

int FetchMultithreaded(int stmt)
{
    auto onExit = OnExit([&](){ cout << stmt << endl; });

    std::thread fetchThread([&]()
    {
        auto onExit = OnExit([&](){ cout << stmt << endl; });
    });

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return FetchMultithreaded(0);
}
```

When I compile this in visual studio 2013, I get the following error:

```
1>Source.cpp(9): error C2516: 'T' : is not a legal base class
1>          Source.cpp(55) : see declaration of 'T'
1>          Source.cpp(55) : see reference to class template instantiation 'OnExitImpl<void (__cdecl *)(void)>' being compiled
```

When I tried it on http://ideone.com/O6I9nj , I just get a ton of errors about std::forward, not sure what's happening there. Not sure which compiler that's using though.

The visual studio error message has me thinking it's a compiler bug, since it seems to treat the lambda as a function pointer...

Edit: After adding the template argument to std::forward, it now compiles (but doesn't link, for other reasons) on Ideone, but doesn't change anything for visual studio. That feeds my suspicion that it's a compiler bug.

Edit 2: In any case, I've worked around the issue by adding the following code:

```
template <typename Ret>
struct FnPtrWrapper
{
    FnPtrWrapper(Ret (*fn)(void)) : _fn(fn)
    {
        assert(fn);
    }

    Ret operator()() const
    {
        return (*_fn)();
    }

private:
    Ret (*_fn)(void);
};

template <typename Ret>
OnExitImpl<FnPtrWrapper<Ret>> OnExit(Ret(*fn)(void))
{
    return OnExitImpl<FnPtrWrapper<Ret>>(fn);
}
```

It seems strange that this fixes it, since the lambda I was using that triggered the error actually captured a function parameter, and thus should not be convertible to a function pointer...

Comment: You need to specify the template argument for `std::forward`, see this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7779900/241631 If you make that change your code compiles, but crashes at runtime because as written, the destructor of a joinable thread is called - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/470df8207096c09b

Comment: Thanks, it compiles on Ideone now, but still no luck on visual studio. I don't really care about the crashing, as this is a simplification of another program.

Comment: @Columbo - I hope not, as that would severely hobble the point of lambdas in C++11.

Comment: @Bwmat Whoops. I didn't even read the error message. You should, it makes for a good laugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a VC++ bug which I believe to have encountered before (on SO). Smallest reproducing sample:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct B { static_assert(std::is_class<T>::value, "T not a class"); }; // (2)

int main()
{
    []{
        auto a = []{};
        static_assert( std::is_class<decltype(a)>::value, "Not a class" ); // (1)
        B<decltype(a)> b;
    }();
}
```

[**Demo on rextester's VC++**](http://rextester.com/OGPOE99684).

Note how the code has to be **inside an outer lambda** for the error to occur.
While (1) succeeds, the declaration of `b` leads to (2) failing with

> source_file.cpp(4) : error C2338: T not a class 
>   source_file.cpp(11) : **see reference to class template '`B<void (__cdecl *)(void)>`' being compiled**

Which indicates that the template argument `decltype(a)` is denoting a pointer-to-function type, while also denoting a class type.