# How remove_reference disable template argument deductions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779900/why-is-template-argument-deduction-disabled-with-stdforward), template argument deduction is disallowed for `std::forward`, and `std::remove_reference` is helping us to achieve that. But how does using `remove_reference` prevent template deduction from happening here?

```
template <class S>
S&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<S>::type& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<S&&>(t);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`S` in the expression `typename std::remove_reference<S>::type` is a **non-deduced context** (specifically because `S` appears in the *nested-name-specifier* of a type specified using a *qualified-id*). Non-deduced contexts are, as the name suggests, contexts in which the template argument cannot be deduced.

This case provides an easy example to understand why. Say I had:

```
int i;
forward(i);
```

What would `S` be? It could be `int`, `int&`, or `int&&` - all of those types would yield the correct argument type for the function. It's simply impossible for the compiler to determine *which* `S` you really mean here - so it doesn't try. It's non-deducible, so you have to explicitly provide which `S` you mean:

```
forward<int&>(i); // oh, got it, you meant S=int&
```

Comment: "I could have an entirely unrelated type `Foo` for which I specialize `remove_reference<Foo>` to have the type `int`." That's technically UB :)

Comment: @T.C., why would that be UB? Isn't it "only" terrible design, just like implementing `operator+` to make a subtraction-like operation? Or maybe it is UB because we are specializing a `std::` function? Ok, just that: [_The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `remove_reference` is undefined._](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)