# No matching function for call std::forward(const std::string &) with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a movable wrapper to non-copyable, non-movable class, however I have a problem passing a `const std::string` variable to the constructor. The minimal example below produces following error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct X {
    std::string x;

    X(const std::string &x) : x(x) {}
    X(const X &x) = delete;
    X(X &&x) = delete;
};

struct Wrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<X> x;

    Wrapper(const Wrapper & wrapper) = delete;
    Wrapper(Wrapper && wrapper) = default;

    template<typename... Args>
    Wrapper(Args&&... args) : x(std::make_unique<X>(std::forward(args)...)) {}
};

int main() {
    const std::string XXX = "XXX";
    Wrapper w{XXX};
    std::cout << w.x->x << std::endl;
}
```

Error message here:

```
forwarding.cc:21:53: error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
    Wrapper(Args&&... args) : x(std::make_unique<X>(std::forward(args)...)) {}
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
forwarding.cc:26:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Wrapper::Wrapper<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > &>' requested here
    Wrapper w{XXX};
            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/move.h:73:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/move.h:84:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: AFAIK forward need to get template argument passed explicitly in your case `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Comment: To complement Vittorio's great answer, if you want to know how template argument deduction is turned off for `std::forward`, resulting in an error and not weird behavior, then you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418089/how-remove-reference-disable-template-argument-deductions).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass template parameters to `std::forward`:

```
std::forward<Args>(args)...
```

This is because `std::forward` needs some way of knowing the "original value category" of `args...`, which is impossible through *template argument deduction* alone as `args` is always an lvalue.

Lvalues will deduced as *lvalue references* in the context of template argument deduction for *forwarding references* (as a special rule), so `std::forward` can do its job by looking at the types inside `Args...`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew, I was missing something like that, but I didn't know, how to use it with parameter pack